# What are useful JavaScript methods that extends built-in objects?

Tags: javascript

What are your most useful, most practical methods that extends built-in JavaScript objects like String, Array, Date, Boolean, Math, etc.?

**String**

- [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1141475#1141475)
- [trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1141469#1141469)
- [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137468#1137468)
- [replaceAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579) & [replaceAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1141816#1141816)

**Array**

- [indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137481#1137481)

**Date**

- [toMidnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1140330#1140330)

**Note :** Please post one extended method per answer.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127423

Answer (score 41):

**String Replace All :**

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace)
{
    //if replace is not sent, return original string otherwise it will
    //replace search string with 'undefined'.
    if (replace === undefined) {
        return this.toString();
    }

    return this.replace(new RegExp('[' + search + ']', 'g'), replace);
};

var str = 'ABCADRAE';
alert(str.replaceAll('A','X')); // output : XBCXDRXE
```

Comment: This is a nice enhancement but to make it even better you could add two parameters to the function definition and use them instead of arguments array. This will shorten the code to two lines. Personally I don't see any point of using arguments array if your function doesn't need to accept arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: RaYell, what you said makes sense. Will edit the post.

Comment: Another improvement: if you add any regexp special characters you might get unexpected results. i.e. if you pass '.' as a search string you will replace all the characters. To avoid that change your regex to something like new RegExp('[' + search ']')

Comment: That's a great catch buddy. You should start editing these posts! :)

Comment: @RaYell - that won't work if you want to replace more than one character at a time, e.g. `'foobar'.replaceAll('foo')`. I think it's better to make it clear that a regexp is accepted as the first argument.

Comment: (actually it will work for my example, but hopefully my point makes sense :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I like this one..

Comment: Indeed that may not work correctly if you replace words with that. Then perhaps a better solution would if be to check what type the search parameter is. If it's a string you could then just escape all special characters, if it's a regex (typeof is object) then you could just use it as it is.

Comment: Another small fix: if replace is undefined you should return this.toString();, because this contains String object not an actual string.

Comment: I posted below another implementation of replaceAll method that correctly handles both string and regular expressions, it uses split and join methods instead of creating regular expressions and doing replaces with them.

Comment: This seem to be buggy in some cases.. probably because of unwanted parsing of content as regex

Comment: By using square brackets in your RegExp, you are telling it to find any instance of each character in the source, not a match to the whole string.  You should use parens, not square brackets.

Answer (score 38):

Here's another implementation of `String.replaceAll()` method

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace) {
    if (replace === undefined) {
        return this.toString();
    }
    return this.split(search).join(replace);
}
```

The difference between this one and solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579) is that this implementation handles correctly regexp special characters in strings as well as allows for word matching

Comment: Why would you need to do .toString? If replace is undefined, you are assigning original object back to itself.

e.g. string test = "hello";
     test = test.replace("hello");

Comment: If I remove toString() and run this I will get an object not a string. Try using typeof on the returned value (tested in FF & Firebug, don't know if other browsers handle that in different way).

Answer (score 16):

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf || function (item) {
    for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === item) return i;
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Usage:

```
var list = ["my", "array", "contents"];
alert(list.indexOf("contents"));     // outputs 2
```

Comment: This method is implemented in most browsers so you could add an existence check before overwriting something that can be already done. IMO you should wrap this code inside if (Array.prototype.indexOf === undefined) {...}

Comment: RaYell, updated the code not to redefine indexOf if it's already present.

Answer (score 9):

There are a ton of String.prototype functions from [James Padolsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21677/j-p)

https://github.com/padolsey/string.prototype

These include:

- camelize
- contains
- count
- enclose
- extract
- forEach
- forEachWord
- linkify
- many
- randomize
- remove
- reverse
- shorten
- sort
- toDOM
- trim
- wrap

Comment: @P6345uk A bit late, but fixed the link.

Answer (score 8):

### String.format

```
String.prototype.format = function (values) {

    var regex = /\{([\w-]+)(?:\:([\w\.]*)(?:\((.*?)?\))?)?\}/g;

    var getValue = function (key) {
            if (values == null || typeof values === 'undefined') return null;

            var value = values[key];
            var type = typeof value;

            return type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? value : null;
        };

    return this.replace(regex, function (match) {
        //match will look like {sample-match}
        //key will be 'sample-match';
        var key = match.substr(1, match.length - 2);

        var value = getValue(key);

        return value != null ? value : match;
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
alert('Program: {key1} {key2}'.format({ 'key1' : 'Hello', 'key2' : 'World' })); //alerts Program: hello world
```

Comment: thats a good one. Would be really cool if it was extended to mimick the C# one where you can specify a context sensitive formatting for dates/numbers/objects eg. String.Format("{0:d}", val)

Comment: I think Microsoft's ASP.NET Ajax library has string.Format which mimics C#'s string.Format method.

Comment: You are right Nosredna, fixed the post.

Answer (score 7):

```
// left trim
String.prototype.ltrim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, '');
}

// right trim
String.prototype.rtrim = function () {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/, '');
}

// left and right trim
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.ltrim().rtrim();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**String Padding :**

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (length, character) { 
     return new Array(length - this.length + 1).join(character || ' ') + this; 
}
'trial'.padLeft(7, 'X'); // output : 'XXtrial'
'trial'.padLeft(7);      // output : '  trial'



String.prototype.padRight = function (length, character) { 
     return this + new Array(length - this.length + 1).join(character || ' '); 
}
'trial'.padRight(7, 'X'); // output : 'trialXX'
'trial'.padRight(7);      // output : 'trial  '
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP.JS is a very nice effort to port most of PHP's functions to JavaScript. They currently have an extremely impressive list:

Online at: http://phpjs.org/functions/index

Answer (score 3):

**Function.prototype.bind** from the Prototype library.

Similar to `call` and `apply` but allows you to return a reference to a function that is called in a particular context instead of executing it immediately. Also allows you to curry parameters. It's so useful that it became a part of ECMAScript 5 and is already being implemented natively in browsers.

```
Function.prototype.bind = function() {
  var __method = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), object = args.shift();
  return function() {
    var local_args = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    if (this !== window) local_args.push(this);
    return __method.apply(object, local_args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The various list manipulation prototypes are always great. Since you want only one per post, I'll just post `foldl`, which I discovered via SML (it "folds" the list, left to right, it has a counter part in `foldr` of course).

```
Array.prototype.foldl = function(fnc,start) {
    var a = start;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        a = fnc(this[i],a);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Some trivial examples could be:

```
var l = ["hello" , "world"];
l.foldl(function(i, acc) { return acc+" "+i; }, "") // => returns "hello world"
```

Sadly, the failure of standard DOM methods to return true arrays makes alot of these such methods rather useless. And if you're using a Lib of some sort, they often define methods like these already (map, filter, exists, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**Date.toMidnight**

```
Date.prototype.toMidnight = function(){ 
  this.setMinutes(0); 
  this.setSeconds(0); 
  this.setHours(0) 
}
```

Comment: Poorly named, since it modifies the date object, instead of returning a different value like other toX methods.

Answer (score 1):

Array contains:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === obj) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Usage:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
alert(arr.contains(2));
```

This little helper function tells you if your array contains an object. If it does then the index of the object is returned, otherwise -1 is returned.

Free Friday afternoon tip: don't ever ever ever modify the Object prototype. That would be just asking for a whole world of pain - I learnt this the hard way :)

Comment: That's the same as Array.indexOf() method posted above. I would suggest going for indexOf since it's already implemented in most browsers.

Comment: I think it's fine to modify the object prototype in some circumstances - so long as you aren't developing Yet Another JavaScript Library, that is. It just means you have to be careful when iterating over object members (i.e. use hasOwnProperty) - but of course, you could add a method to the object prototype that handles the iteration for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the nice extension for the Date object that allows you to format the date very easily. It uses PHP's date syntax so those familiar with PHP will get it in no time. Others have a huge list of possible switches on the site as well. Personally I haven't found easier way to format dates to various formats.

[Date Format](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format)

Answer (score 1):

A collection of functions I use a lot can be found here:

http://svn.asplib.org/asplib1.2/core/string.asp

http://docs.hyperweb.no/objects/String/

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Array.Map function outlined by Scott Koon a couple of times.

http://www.lazycoder.com/weblog/2009/08/12/a-simple-map-function-for-plain-javascript-arrays/

```
Array.prototype.map = function(fn) {
    var r = [];
    var l = this.length;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        r.push(fn(this[i]));
    }
    return r; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

These two are wrappers for inserting and deleting elements from a particular position in an Array because I don't like the name `splice`.

```
// insert element at index
Array.prototype.insertAt = function(element, index) {
    this.splice(index, 0, element);
}

// delete element from index
Array.prototype.removeAt = function(index) {
    this.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Some more useful Array methods to get away from using indexes:

```
Array.prototype.first = function() {
    return this[0] || undefined;
};

Array.prototype.last = function() {
    if(this.length > 0) {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
    return undefined;
};

Array.prototype.max = function(array){
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};

Array.prototype.min = function(array){
    return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};
```

Some useful functions from the MooTools library:

**[Function.delay](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:delay)**

Used to execute a function after the given milliseconds have elapsed.

```
// alerts "hello" after 2 seconds.
(function() {
    alert("hello");
}).delay(2000);    ​
```

**[Number.times](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Number#Number:times)**

Similar to Ruby's times method for numbers, this accepts a function and executes it N times where N is the numbers value.

```
// logs hello 5 times
(5).times(function() {
    console.log("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the prototype chain like this:

```
String.prototype.AddWorld = function() { return this+'World' }

"Hello ".AddWorld(); // returns the string "Hello World"
```

Comment: -1 as it is not useful or practical.

Comment: This would be more usefull `String.prototype.appendWord=function(word){ this = this +" "+ word;}` `"Hello".appendWord("World");`

Answer (score 0):

```
// This replaces all instances of 'from' to 'to' even when
// 'from' and 'to' are similar (i.e .replaceAll('a', 'a '))
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(from, to) {
    var k = this;
    var i = 0;
    var j = from.length;
    var l = to.length;

    while (i <= k.length)
        if (k.substring(i, i + j) == from) {
        k = k.substring(0, i) + k.substring(i).replace(from, to);
        i += l;
    }
    else
        i++;

    return k;
};
```

Comment: It is easier to use the 'g' (global match) flag and do a regular replace. `"abaababa".replace(/a/g, "c") => "cbccbcbc"`

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice article at http://maiaco.com/articles/js/missingArrayFunctions.php describing six helpful functions to add to the Array prototype.  The functions are linearSearch (same as indexOf given in another answer), binarySearch, retainAll, removeAll, unique, and addAll.  The article also includes the JavaScript code for each of the six functions and example code showing how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prototype function for capitalizing a string:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library or for Angular use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library.