# How do I replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Given a string:

```
string = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
```

This seems to only remove the first occurrence of `abc` in the string above:

```
string = string.replace('abc', '');
```

How do I replace *all* occurrences of it?

Comment: When replacing all occurrences of `aba` in `ababa` with `ca`, which result do you expect? `caba`? `abca`? `cca`?

Comment: `String.prototype.replaceAll()` is now a standard part of ECMAScript https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replaceall, documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll and shipped in Safari 13.1, Firefox 77 and Chrome Dev/Canary and will ship in Chrome 85. From the docs:  “If *searchValue* is a string, replaces all occurrences of *searchValue* (as if `.split(searchValue).join(replaceValue)` or a global & properly-escaped regular expression had been used). If *searchValue* is a non-global regular expression, throws an exception”

Comment: Use regex instead of string, should look like `str.replace(/abc/g, '');` so g to get all matches.

Answer (score 2391, accepted):

In the latest versions of most popular browsers, you can use [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)
as shown here:

```js
let result = "1 abc 2 abc 3".replaceAll("abc", "xyz");
// `result` is "1 xyz 2 xyz 3"
```

But check [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll) or another compatibility table first to make sure the browsers you're targeting have added support for it first.

---

For Node.js and compatibility with older/non-current browsers:

**Note: Don't use the following solution in performance critical code.**

As an alternative to regular expressions for a simple literal string, you could use

```js
str = "Test abc test test abc test...".split("abc").join("");
```

The general pattern is

```js
str.split(search).join(replacement)
```

This used to be faster in some cases than using `replaceAll` and a regular expression, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore in modern browsers.

Benchmark: https://jsben.ch/TZYzj

#### Conclusion:

If you have a performance-critical use case (e.g., processing hundreds of strings), use the regular expression method. But for most typical use cases, this is well worth not having to worry about special characters.

Comment: I discourage from using replaceAll at this moment (2020). It is not supported by some browsers that had updates in this year https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll It is too early

Comment: NodeJS supports `replaceAll` in 15.x versions.

Comment: what to do in case-sensitive case

Comment: The benchmark's plain replace function is not the equivalent of regex /g. "If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced. "  EX: replaceAll_0("foo bar foo")  => "bar foo" when it should just be "bar".  -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: These solutions are way more readable than the reg-ex based solutions. Imo this should be the top answer.

Answer (score 5213):

**As of August 2020:** [Modern browsers have support](https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replaceall) for the [`String.replaceAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) defined by the ECMAScript 2021 language specification.

---

**For older/legacy browsers:**

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}
```

Here is how this answer evolved:

```js
str = str.replace(/abc/g, '');
```

In response to comment "what's if 'abc' is passed as a variable?":

```js
var find = 'abc';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

str = str.replace(re, '');
```

In response to [Click Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49153/click-upvote)'s comment, you could simplify it even more:

```js
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

**Note:** Regular expressions contain special (meta) characters, and as such it is dangerous to blindly pass an argument in the `find` function above without pre-processing it to escape those characters.  This is covered in the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)'s [JavaScript Guide on Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping), where they present the following utility function (which has changed at least twice since this answer was originally written, so make sure to check the MDN site for potential updates):

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

So in order to make the `replaceAll()` function above safer, it could be modified to the following if you also include `escapeRegExp`:

```js
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}
```

Comment: In `escapeRegExp` the `]` and `}` are extra (not necessary to be escaped). It is better to be like: `.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{|\\]/g, "\\$&")`

Comment: You also need to escape the replacement string (consider how `escapeRegExp` uses `$&` in the replacement string for special behavior).  Change last `replace` in last code block to `replace.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/2730641 Test case: `replaceAll('abc def abc', 'abc', '$&@%#!')  // Censor 'abc'`

Comment: @Sean Bright please read the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/63587267/8798220

Comment: @NishargShah the first sentence of this answer references the `replaceAll()` method.

Comment: Yes, I know, I am talking about the comments that this answer has, please check that.

Comment: @NishargShah I do not remember what comments were on this answer 2 years ago but if you would like to edit this answer and credit yourself feel free.

Comment: No need @SeanBright, I just want to inform you that, If you are seeing the code of someone and you liked it and you want to improve your answer based on that, then specifying that user name in your answer is good.

Answer (score 2536):

For the sake of completeness, I got to thinking about which method I should use to do this. There are basically two ways to do this as suggested by the other answers on this page.

**Note:** In general, extending the built-in prototypes in JavaScript is generally not recommended. I am providing as extensions on the String prototype simply for purposes of illustration, showing different implementations of a hypothetical standard method on the `String` built-in prototype.

---

#### Regular Expression Based Implementation

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

#### Split and Join (Functional) Implementation

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

---

Not knowing too much about how regular expressions work behind the scenes in terms of efficiency, I tended to lean toward the split and join implementation in the past without thinking about performance. When I did wonder which was more efficient, and by what margin, I used it as an excuse to find out.

On my Chrome Windows 8 machine, **the regular expression based implementation is the fastest**, with the **split and join implementation being 53% slower**. Meaning the regular expressions are twice as fast for the lorem ipsum input I used.

Check out this [**benchmark**](http://jsben.ch/#/LFfWA) running these two implementations against each other.

---

As noted in the comment below by @ThomasLeduc and others, there could be an issue with the regular expression-based implementation if `search` contains certain characters which are reserved as [special characters in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters). The implementation assumes that the caller will escape the string beforehand or will only pass strings that are without the characters in the table in *[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters)* (MDN).

MDN also provides an implementation to escape our strings. It would be nice if this was also standardized as `RegExp.escape(str)`, but alas, it does not exist:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

We could call `escapeRegExp` within our `String.prototype.replaceAll` implementation, however, I'm not sure how much this will affect the performance (potentially even for strings for which the escape is not needed, like all alphanumeric strings).

Comment: In 2021 [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) natively exist. So this implementation should be checked first before use.

Comment: m using nestjs, so typescript showing error that replaceAll is not method of String prototype, any solution for this?

Answer (score 103):

These are the most common and readable methods.

```js
var str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc"
```

**Method 1:**

```js
str = str.replace(/abc/g, "replaced text");
```

**Method 2:**

```js
str = str.split("abc").join("replaced text");
```

**Method 3:**

```js
str = str.replace(new RegExp("abc", "g"), "replaced text");
```

**Method 4:**

```js
while(str.includes("abc")){
   str = str.replace("abc", "replaced text");
}
```

Output:

```js
console.log(str);
// Test replaced text test test replaced text test test test replaced text test test replaced text
```

Comment: I found method 1 most easy & reliable till now. its also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214896/6908282).

Comment: method no 2 works great in Sharepoint SPFx for replacing dynamic strings - other methods are explicitly blocked by compiler rules

Answer (score 97):

Use word boundaries (`\b`)

```js
'a cat is not a caterpillar'.replace(/\bcat\b/gi,'dog');
//"a dog is not a caterpillar"
```

This is a simple regex that avoids replacing parts of words in most cases. However, a dash `-` is still considered a word boundary. So conditionals can be used in this case to avoid replacing strings like `cool-cat`:

```js
'a cat is not a cool-cat'.replace(/\bcat\b/gi,'dog');//wrong
//"a dog is not a cool-dog" -- nips
'a cat is not a cool-cat'.replace(/(?:\b([^-]))cat(?:\b([^-]))/gi,'$1dog$2');
//"a dog is not a cool-cat"
```

---

Basically, this question is the same as the question here:
[Replace " ' " with " '' " in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499075/javascript-replace-with/9499926)

Regexp isn't the only way to replace multiple occurrences of a substring, far from it. Think flexible, think split!

```js
var newText = "the cat looks like a cat".split('cat').join('dog');
```

Alternatively, to prevent replacing word parts—which the approved answer will do, too! You can get around this issue using regular expressions that are, I admit, somewhat more complex and as an upshot of that, a tad slower, too:

```js
var regText = "the cat looks like a cat".replace(/(?:(^|[^a-z]))(([^a-z]*)(?=cat)cat)(?![a-z])/gi,"$1dog");
```

The output is the same as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript/1145525#1145525), however, using the `/cat/g` expression on this string:

```js
var oops = 'the cat looks like a cat, not a caterpillar or coolcat'.replace(/cat/g,'dog');
//returns "the dog looks like a dog, not a dogerpillar or cooldog" ??
```

Oops indeed, this probably isn't what you want. What is, then? IMHO, a regex that only replaces 'cat' conditionally (i.e., not part of a word), like so:

```js
var caterpillar = 'the cat looks like a cat, not a caterpillar or coolcat'.replace(/(?:(^|[^a-z]))(([^a-z]*)(?=cat)cat)(?![a-z])/gi,"$1dog");
//return "the dog looks like a dog, not a caterpillar or coolcat"
```

My guess is, this meets your needs. It's not foolproof, of course, but it should be enough to get you started. I'd recommend reading some more on these pages. This'll prove useful in perfecting this expression to meet your specific needs.

- *[RegExp (regular expression) object](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml)*
- *[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)*

---

Here is an example of `.replace` used with a callback function. In this case, it dramatically simplifies the expression *and* provides even more flexibility, like replacing with correct capitalisation or replacing both `cat` and `cats` in one go:

```js
'Two cats are not 1 Cat! They\'re just cool-cats, you caterpillar'
   .replace(/(^|.\b)(cat)(s?\b.|$)/gi,function(all,char1,cat,char2)
    {
       // Check 1st, capitalize if required
       var replacement = (cat.charAt(0) === 'C' ? 'D' : 'd') + 'og';
       if (char1 === ' ' && char2 === 's')
       { // Replace plurals, too
           cat = replacement + 's';
       }
       else
       { // Do not replace if dashes are matched
           cat = char1 === '-' || char2 === '-' ? cat : replacement;
       }
       return char1 + cat + char2;//return replacement string
    });
//returns:
//Two dogs are not 1 Dog! They're just cool-cats, you caterpillar
```

Answer (score 87):

Match against a global regular expression:

```
anotherString = someString.replace(/cat/g, 'dog');
```

Answer (score 60):

```js
str = str.replace(/abc/g, '');
```

Or try the `replaceAll` method, as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579):

```js
str = str.replaceAll('abc', '');
```

or:

```js
var search = 'abc';
str = str.replaceAll(search, '');
```

**EDIT:** Clarification about `replaceAll` availability

The `replaceAll` method is added to `String`'s prototype. This means it will be available for all string objects/literals.

Example:

```js
var output = "test this".replaceAll('this', 'that'); // output is 'test that'.
output = output.replaceAll('that', 'this'); // output is 'test this'
```

Answer (score 42):

Use a regular expression:

```
str.replace(/abc/g, '');
```

Answer (score 38):

### Performance

Today 27.12.2019 I perform tests on [macOS v10.13.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra) for the chosen solutions.

**Conclusions**

- The `str.replace(/abc/g, '');` (**C**) is a good cross-browser fast solution for all strings.
- Solutions based on `split-join` (**A,B**) or `replace` (**C,D**) are fast
- Solutions based on `while` (**E,F,G,H**) are slow - usually ~4 times slower for small strings and about ~3000 times (!) slower for long strings
- The recurrence solutions (**RA,RB**) are slow and do not work for long strings

I also create my own solution. It looks like currently it is the shortest one which does the question job:

```
str.split`abc`.join``
```

```js
str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
str = str.split`abc`.join``

console.log(str);
```

### Details

The tests were performed on Chrome 79.0, Safari 13.0.4 and Firefox 71.0 (64 bit). The tests `RA` and `RB` use recursion. Results

[image]

### Short string - 55 characters

You can run tests on your machine [HERE](https://jsperf.com/remove-substring-small/1). Results for Chrome:

[image]

### Long string: 275 000 characters

The recursive solutions **RA** and **RB** gives

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

For 1M characters they even break Chrome

[image]

I try to perform tests for 1M characters for other solutions, but **E,F,G,H** takes so much time that browser ask me to break script so I shrink test string to 275K characters. You can run tests on your machine [HERE](https://jsperf.com/remove-substring-big/1). Results for Chrome

[image]

Code used in tests

```js
var t="Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc"; // .repeat(5000)
var log = (version,result) => console.log(`${version}: ${result}`);


function A(str) {
  return str.split('abc').join('');
}

function B(str) {
  return str.split`abc`.join``; // my proposition
}


function C(str) {
  return str.replace(/abc/g, '');
}

function D(str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp("abc", "g"), '');
}

function E(str) {
  while (str.indexOf('abc') !== -1) { str = str.replace('abc', ''); }
  return str;
}

function F(str) {
  while (str.indexOf('abc') !== -1) { str = str.replace(/abc/, ''); }
  return str;
}

function G(str) {
  while(str.includes("abc")) { str = str.replace('abc', ''); }
  return str;
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56989553/860099
function H(str)
{
    let i = -1
    let find = 'abc';
    let newToken = '';

    if (!str)
    {
        if ((str == null) && (find == null)) return newToken;
        return str;
    }

    while ((
        i = str.indexOf(
            find, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
        )) !== -1
    )
    {
        str = str.substring(0, i) +
            newToken +
            str.substring(i + find.length);
    }
    return str;
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870785/860099
function RA(string, prevstring) {
  var omit = 'abc';
  var place = '';
  if (prevstring && string === prevstring)
    return string;
  prevstring = string.replace(omit, place);
  return RA(prevstring, string)
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26107132/860099
function RB(str) {
  var find = 'abc';
  var replace = '';
  var i = str.indexOf(find);
  if (i > -1){
    str = str.replace(find, replace);
    i = i + replace.length;
    var st2 = str.substring(i);
    if(st2.indexOf(find) > -1){
      str = str.substring(0,i) + RB(st2, find, replace);
    }
  }
  return str;
}




log('A ', A(t));
log('B ', B(t));
log('C ', C(t));
log('D ', D(t));
log('E ', E(t));
log('F ', F(t));
log('G ', G(t));
log('H ', H(t));
log('RA', RA(t)); // use reccurence
log('RB', RB(t)); // use reccurence
```

```html
<p style="color:red">This snippet only presents codes used in tests. It not perform test itself!<p>
```

Comment: Now this is one hell of an in depth answer! Thank you very much! Although, what I'm curious about is why the "new RegExp(...)" syntax gives that much of an improvement.

Answer (score 28):

Loop it until number occurrences comes to 0, like this:

```js
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
    while (str.indexOf(find) > -1) {
        str = str.replace(find, replace);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This method is dangerous, do not use it. If the replacement string contains the search keyword, then an infinite loop will occur. At the very least, store the result of `.indexOf` in a variable, and use this variable as the second parameter of `.indexOf` (minus length of keyword, plus length of replacement string).

Answer (score 27):

This is the **fastest** version that *doesn't use regular expressions*.

[Revised jsperf](http://jsperf.com/replace-all-vs-split-join/10)

```
replaceAll = function(string, omit, place, prevstring) {
  if (prevstring && string === prevstring)
    return string;
  prevstring = string.replace(omit, place);
  return replaceAll(prevstring, omit, place, string)
}
```

It is almost **twice** as fast as the split and join method.

As pointed out in a comment here, this will not work if your `omit` variable contains `place`, as in: `replaceAll("string", "s", "ss")`, because it will always be able to replace another occurrence of the word.

There is another jsperf with variants on my recursive replace that go even faster (http://jsperf.com/replace-all-vs-split-join/12)!

- Update July 27th 2017: It looks like RegExp now has the fastest performance in the recently released Chrome 59.

Comment: Re *"almost twice as fast"*: What was it tested on? Browser, JavaScript runtime, hardware, operating system, etc. All with versions and specifications (e.g. clock speed, CPU type, etc.).

Answer (score 24):

If what you want to find is already in a string, and you don't have a regex escaper handy, you can use join/split:

```js
function replaceMulti(haystack, needle, replacement)
{
    return haystack.split(needle).join(replacement);
}

someString = 'the cat looks like a cat';
console.log(replaceMulti(someString, 'cat', 'dog'));
```

Answer (score 20):

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  var i = str.indexOf(find);
  if (i > -1){
    str = str.replace(find, replace); 
    i = i + replace.length;
    var st2 = str.substring(i);
    if(st2.indexOf(find) > -1){
      str = str.substring(0,i) + replaceAll(st2, find, replace);
    }       
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I like this method (it looks a little cleaner):

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp("cat","g"), "dog");
```

Answer (score 18):

Of course in **2021** the right answer is:

#### [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
console.log(
  'Change this and this for me'.replaceAll('this','that') // Normal case
);
console.log(
  'aaaaaa'.replaceAll('aa','a') // Challenged case
);
```

If you don't want to deal with [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) + [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

**But what if the browser is from before 2020?**

In this case we need **[polyfill](https://w3ctag.github.io/polyfills/)** (forcing older browsers to support new features) *(I think for a few years will be necessary)*.
I could not find a completely right method in answers. So I suggest this function that will be defined as a polyfill.

##### My suggested options for `replaceAll` polyfill:

###### `replaceAll` polyfill (with global-flag error) (more principled version)

```js
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll) { // Check if the native function not exist
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'replaceAll', { // Define replaceAll as a prototype for (Mother/Any) String
        configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: false, // Editable & non-enumerable property (As it should be)
        value: function(search, replace) { // Set the function by closest input names (For good info in consoles)
            return this.replace( // Using native String.prototype.replace()
                Object.prototype.toString.call(search) === '[object RegExp]' // IsRegExp?
                    ? search.global // Is the RegEx global?
                        ? search // So pass it
                        : function(){throw new TypeError('replaceAll called with a non-global RegExp argument')}() // If not throw an error
                    : RegExp(String(search).replace(/[.^$*+?()[{|\\]/g, "\\$&"), "g"), // Replace all reserved characters with '\' then make a global 'g' RegExp
                replace); // passing second argument
        }
    });
}
```

###### `replaceAll` polyfill (With handling global-flag missing by itself) (my first preference) - [Why?](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall/issues/16)

```js
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll) { // Check if the native function not exist
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'replaceAll', { // Define replaceAll as a prototype for (Mother/Any) String
        configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: false, // Editable & non-enumerable property (As it should be)
        value: function(search, replace) { // Set the function by closest input names (For good info in consoles)
            return this.replace( // Using native String.prototype.replace()
                Object.prototype.toString.call(search) === '[object RegExp]' // IsRegExp?
                    ? search.global // Is the RegEx global?
                        ? search // So pass it
                        : RegExp(search.source, /\/([a-z]*)$/.exec(search.toString())[1] + 'g') // If not, make a global clone from the RegEx
                    : RegExp(String(search).replace(/[.^$*+?()[{|\\]/g, "\\$&"), "g"), // Replace all reserved characters with '\' then make a global 'g' RegExp
                replace); // passing second argument
        }
    });
}
```

###### Minified (my first preference):

```js
if(!String.prototype.replaceAll){Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'replaceAll',{configurable:!0,writable:!0,enumerable:!1,value:function(search,replace){return this.replace(Object.prototype.toString.call(search)==='[object RegExp]'?search.global?search:RegExp(search.source,/\/([a-z]*)$/.exec(search.toString())[1]+'g'):RegExp(String(search).replace(/[.^$*+?()[{|\\]/g,"\\$&"),"g"),replace)}})}
```

###### Try it:

```js
if(!String.prototype.replaceAll){Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'replaceAll',{configurable:!0,writable:!0,enumerable:!1,value:function(search,replace){return this.replace(Object.prototype.toString.call(search)==='[object RegExp]'?search.global?search:RegExp(search.source,/\/([a-z]*)$/.exec(search.toString())[1]+'g'):RegExp(String(search).replace(/[.^$*+?()[{|\\]/g,"\\$&"),"g"),replace)}})}

console.log(
  'Change this and this for me'.replaceAll('this','that')
); // Change that and that for me

console.log(
  'aaaaaa'.replaceAll('aa','a')
); // aaa

console.log(
  '{} (*) (*) (RegEx) (*) (\*) (\\*) [reserved characters]'.replaceAll('(*)','X')
); // {} X X (RegEx) X X (\*) [reserved characters]

console.log(
  'How (replace) (XX) with $1?'.replaceAll(/(xx)/gi,'$$1')
); // How (replace) ($1) with $1?

console.log(
  'Here is some numbers 1234567890 1000000 123123.'.replaceAll(/\d+/g,'***')
); // Here is some numbers *** *** *** and need to be replaced.

console.log(
  'Remove numbers under 233: 236   229  711   200   5'.replaceAll(/\d+/g, function(m) {
    return parseFloat(m) < 233 ? '' : m
  })
); // Remove numbers under 233: 236     711

console.log(
  'null'.replaceAll(null,'x')
); // x


// The difference between My first preference and the original:
// Now in 2022 with browsers > 2020 it should throw an error (But possible it be changed in future)

//   console.log(
//      'xyz ABC abc ABC abc xyz'.replaceAll(/abc/i,'')
//   );

// Browsers < 2020:
// xyz     xyz
// Browsers > 2020
// TypeError: String.prototype.replaceAll called with a non-global RegExp
```

###### Browser support:

- [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) and later (rested on [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11)).
- All other browsers (after 2012).

The result is **the same as the native replaceAll** in case of the first argument input is:
`null`, `undefined`, `Object`, `Function`, `Date`, ... , `RegExp`, `Number`, `String`, ...

Ref: *[22.1.3.19 String.prototype.replaceAll ( searchValue, replaceValue)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replaceall)*
*+ [RegExp Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#syntax)*

**Important note:** As some professionals mention it, many of recursive functions that suggested in answers, will return the wrong result. (Try them with the *challenged* case of the above snippet.)
Maybe some tricky methods like *`.split('searchValue').join('replaceValue')`* or some well managed functions give same result, but definitely with much lower performance than `native replaceAll()` / `polyfill replaceAll()` / `replace() + RegExp`

---

##### Other methods of polyfill assignment

###### Naive, but supports even older browsers *(be better to avoid)*

For example, we can support IE7+ too, by not using [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and using my old naive assignment method:

```js
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll) {
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace) { // <-- Naive method for assignment
        // ... (Polyfill code Here)
    }
}
```

And it should work well for basic uses on IE7+. 
**But** as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491279/7514010) @sebastian-simon explained about, that can make secondary problems in case of more advanced uses. E.g.:

```js
for (var k in 'hi') console.log(k);
// 0
// 1
// replaceAll  <-- ?
```

###### Fully trustable, but heavy

In fact, my suggested option is a little optimistic. Like we trusted the environment (browser and [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)), it is definitely for around 2012-2021. Also it is a *standard/famous* one, so it does not require any special consideration.

But there can be even older browsers *or* some unexpected problems, and polyfills still can support and solve more possible environment problems. So in case we need the maximum support that is possible, we can use *polyfill libraries* like:

https://polyfill.io/

Specially for *replaceAll*:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=String.prototype.replaceAll"></script>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
while (str.indexOf('abc') !== -1)
{
    str = str.replace('abc', '');
}
```

Comment: I already use that in code, and it's very handy! +1

Answer (score 14):

```
var str = "ff ff f f a de def";
str = str.replace(/f/g,'');
alert(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ANHR9/

Answer (score 14):

If the string contains a similar pattern like `abccc`, you can use this:

```
str.replace(/abc(\s|$)/g, "")
```

Answer (score 13):

As of August 2020 there is a [Stage 4 proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-string-replaceall/) to ECMAScript that adds the [`replaceAll`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall) method to `String`.

It's now supported in **Chrome 85+, Edge 85+, Firefox 77+, Safari 13.1+**.

The usage is the same as the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll(searchValue, replaceValue)
```

Here's an example usage:

```
'Test abc test test abc test.'.replaceAll('abc', 'foo'); // -> 'Test foo test test foo test.'
```

---

It's supported in [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=replaceAll), but there exist polyfills:

- [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#stringreplaceall)
- [es-shims](https://github.com/es-shims/String.prototype.replaceAll)

It is supported in the [V8](https://v8.dev/) engine behind an experimental flag `--harmony-string-replaceall`.
Read more on the [V8 website](https://v8.dev/features/string-replaceall).

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), this has been available since Firefox 77 and Chromium 85.

Answer (score 13):

After several trials and a lot of fails, I found that the below function seems to be the best all-rounder when it comes to browser compatibility and ease of use. This is the only working solution for older browsers that I found. (Yes, even though old browser are discouraged and outdated, some legacy applications still make heavy use of [OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) browsers (such as old [Visual Basic 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline) applications or [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) .xlsm macros with forms.)

Anyway, here's the simple function.

```
function replaceAll(str, match, replacement){
   return str.split(match).join(replacement);
}
```

Comment: This has already been suggested or mentioned in 18 other answers, and in the comments under the question. The compatibility considerations are easy to find on [CanIUse](//caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll) and [MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility). This is all mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: well at first glance I didn't find anything mentioning older browsers and OLE implementations in legacy code. Just thought it might help someone no point of downvoting a helpful answer. You don't have to upvote either I just care that someone might find it useful. Thanks for your contribution nevertheless

Answer (score 12):

The previous answers are way too complicated. Just use the *[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)* function like this:

```
str.replace(/your_regex_pattern/g, replacement_string);
```

Example:

```js
var str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";

var res = str.replace(/[abc]+/g, "");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to ensure that the string you are looking for won't exist even after the replacement, you need to use a loop.

For example:

```
var str = 'test aabcbc';
str = str.replace(/abc/g, '');
```

When complete, you will still have 'test abc'!

The simplest loop to solve this would be:

```
var str = 'test aabcbc';
while (str != str.replace(/abc/g, '')){
   str.replace(/abc/g, '');
}
```

But that runs the replacement twice for each cycle. Perhaps (at risk of being voted down) that can be combined for a slightly more efficient but less readable form:

```
var str = 'test aabcbc';
while (str != (str = str.replace(/abc/g, ''))){}
// alert(str); alerts 'test '!
```

This can be particularly useful when looking for duplicate strings.
For example, if we have 'a,,,b' and we wish to remove all duplicate commas.
[In that case, one could do .replace(/,+/g,','), but at some point the regex gets complex and slow enough to loop instead.]

Answer (score 10):

Although people have mentioned the use of regex, there's a better approach if you want to replace the text irrespective of the case of the text. Like uppercase or lowercase. Use the below syntax:

```
// Consider the below example
originalString.replace(/stringToBeReplaced/gi, '');

// The output will be all the occurrences removed irrespective of casing.
```

You can refer to the detailed example [here](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/javascript-hacks-for-html-webpage.html).

Comment: from the example site: 

"/toBeReplacedString/gi is the regex you need to use. Here g represents for global match and i represents case insensitive. By default regex is case sensitive"

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using regular expressions. A few combinations that might help someone:

```
var word = "this,\\ .is*a*test,    '.and? / only /     'a \ test?";
var stri = "This      is    a test         and only a        test";
```

**To replace all non alpha characters,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/([^a-z])/g,' ').replace(/ +/g, ' '));
Result: [this is a test and only a test]
```

**To replace multiple continuous spaces with one space,**

```
console.log(stri.replace(/  +/g,' '));
Result: [This is a test and only a test]
```

**To replace all * characters,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/\*/g,''));
Result: [this,\ .isatest,    '.and? / only /     'a  test?]
```

**To replace question marks (?)**

```
console.log(word.replace(/\?/g,'#'));
Result: [this,\ .is*a*test,    '.and# / only /     'a  test#]
```

**To replace quotation marks,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/'/g,'#'));
Result: [this,\ .is*a*test,    #.and? / only /     #a  test?]
```

**To replace all ' characters,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/,/g,''));
Result: [this\ .is*a*test    '.and? / only /     'a  test?]
```

**To replace a specific word,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/test/g,''));
Result: [this,\ .is*a*,    '.and? / only /     'a  ?]
```

**To replace backslash,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/\\/g,''));
Result: [this, .is*a*test,    '.and? / only /     'a  test?]
```

**To replace forward slash,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/\//g,''));
Result: [this,\ .is*a*test,    '.and?  only      'a  test?]
```

**To replace all spaces,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/ /g,'#'));
Result: [this,\#.is*a*test,####'.and?#/#only#/#####'a##test?]
```

**To replace dots,**

```
console.log(word.replace(/\./g,'#'));
Result: [this,\ #is*a*test,    '#and? / only /     'a  test?]
```

Answer (score 6):

My implementation, very self explanatory

```
function replaceAll(string, token, newtoken) {
    if(token!=newtoken)
    while(string.indexOf(token) > -1) {
        string = string.replace(token, newtoken);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `replaceAll("123434", "1234", "12")` should return `"1234"` but instead returns `"12"`.

Comment: it depends if you allow to replace "recursively" or not.

Comment: replaceAll("abc", "a", "ab") never terminates

Answer (score 6):

I use **p** to store the result from the previous recursion replacement:

```
function replaceAll(s, m, r, p) {
    return s === p || r.contains(m) ? s : replaceAll(s.replace(m, r), m, r, s);
}
```

It will replace all occurrences in the string **s** until it is possible:

```
replaceAll('abbbbb', 'ab', 'a') → 'abbbb' → 'abbb' → 'abb' → 'ab' → 'a'
```

To avoid infinite loop I check if the replacement **r** contains a match **m**:

```
replaceAll('abbbbb', 'a', 'ab') → 'abbbbb'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use below method

```
/**
 * Replace all the occerencess of $find by $replace in $originalString
 * @param  {originalString} input - Raw string.
 * @param  {find} input - Target key word or regex that need to be replaced.
 * @param  {replace} input - Replacement key word
 * @return {String}       Output string
 */
function replaceAll(originalString, find, replace) {
  return originalString.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

The following function works for me:

```
String.prototype.replaceAllOccurence = function(str1, str2, ignore)
{
    return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
} ;
```

Now call the functions like this:

```
"you could be a Project Manager someday, if you work like this.".replaceAllOccurence ("you", "I");
```

Simply copy and paste this code in your browser console to TEST.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of performance related to the main answers, [these are some online tests](http://jsben.ch/BVIHC).

While the following are some performance tests using `console.time()` (they work best in your own console because the time is very short to be seen in the following snippet).

```js
console.time('split and join');
"javascript-test-find-and-replace-all".split('-').join(' ');
console.timeEnd('split and join')

console.time('regular expression');
"javascript-test-find-and-replace-all".replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), ' ');
console.timeEnd('regular expression');

console.time('while');
let str1 = "javascript-test-find-and-replace-all";
while (str1.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
    str1 = str1.replace('-', ' ');
}
console.timeEnd('while');
```

The interesting thing to notice is that if you run them multiple times, the results are always different even though the regular expression solution seems the fastest on average and the `while` loop solution the slowest.

Answer (score 5):

I use split and join or this function:

```
function replaceAll(text, busca, reemplaza) {
  while (text.toString().indexOf(busca) != -1)
    text = text.toString().replace(busca, reemplaza);
  return text;
}
```

Comment: That work wrong in case of `replaceAll('aaaaaa','aa','a')`

Answer (score 5):

There is now a [finished proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall) for integrating `String.prototype.replaceAll` into the official specification. Eventually, developers will not have to come up with their own implementations for `replaceAll` - instead, modern JavaScript engines will support it natively.

The proposal is at stage 4, [which means](https://tc39.es/process-document/) that everything is complete, and all that's left is for browsers to start implementing it.

It [has shipped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#Browser_compatibility) in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Here are the implementation details:

> Per the current TC39 consensus, `String.prototype.replaceAll` behaves identically to `String.prototype.replace` in all cases, **except** for the following two cases:
>
> 1. If `searchValue` is a string, `String.prototype.replace` only replaces a single occurrence of the `searchValue`, whereas `String.prototype.replaceAll` replaces *all* occurrences of the `searchValue` (as if `.split(searchValue).join(replaceValue)` or a global & properly-escaped regular expression had been used).
> 2. If `searchValue` is a non-global regular expression, `String.prototype.replace` replaces a single match, whereas `String.prototype.replaceAll` throws an exception. This is done to avoid the inherent confusion between the lack of a global flag (which implies "do NOT replace all") and the name of the method being called (which strongly suggests "replace all").
>
> Notably, `String.prototype.replaceAll` behaves just like `String.prototype.replace` if `searchValue` is a global regular expression.

You can see a specification-compliant [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#stringreplaceall).

In supported environments, the following snippet will log `foo-bar-baz`, without throwing an error:

```js
const str = 'foo bar baz';
console.log(
  str.replaceAll(' ', '-')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

If using a library is an option for you then you will get the benefits of the testing and community support that goes with a library function. For example, the [string.js](http://stringjs.com/) library has a replaceAll() function that does what you're looking for:

```
// Include a reference to the string.js library and call it (for example) S.
str = S(str).replaceAll('abc', '').s;
```

Answer (score 4):

In my applications, I use a custom function that is the most powerful for this purpose, and even wrapping the `split/join` solution in the simpler case, it is a little bit faster in Chrome 60 and Firefox 54 ([JSBEN.CH](http://jsben.ch/kdv27)) than other solutions. My computer runs Windows 7 64 bits.

The advantage is that this custom function can handle many substitutions at the same time using strings or characters, which can be a shortcut for some applications.

Like the above *split/join* solution, the solution below doesn't have any problems with escape characters, differently than the regular expression approach.

```
function replaceAll(s, find, repl, caseOff, byChar) {
    if (arguments.length<2)
        return false;
    var destDel = ! repl;       // If destDel delete all keys from target
    var isString = !! byChar;   // If byChar, replace set of characters
    if (typeof find !== typeof repl && ! destDel)
        return false;
    if (isString && (typeof find !== "string"))
        return false;

    if (! isString && (typeof find === "string")) {
        return s.split(find).join(destDel ? "" : repl);
    }

    if ((! isString) && (! Array.isArray(find) ||
        (! Array.isArray(repl) && ! destDel)))
        return false;

    // If destOne replace all strings/characters by just one element
    var destOne = destDel ? false : (repl.length === 1);

    // Generally source and destination should have the same size
    if (! destOne && ! destDel && find.length !== repl.length)
        return false

    var prox, sUp, findUp, i, done;
    if (caseOff)  { // Case insensitive

    // Working with uppercase keys and target
    sUp = s.toUpperCase();
    if (isString)
       findUp = find.toUpperCase()
    else
       findUp = find.map(function(el) {
                    return el.toUpperCase();
                });
    }
    else { // Case sensitive
        sUp = s;
        findUp = find.slice(); // Clone array/string
    }

    done = new Array(find.length); // Size: number of keys
    done.fill(null);

    var pos = 0;  // Initial position in target s
    var r = "";   // Initial result
    var aux, winner;
    while (pos < s.length) {       // Scanning the target
        prox  = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
        winner = -1;  // No winner at the start
        for (i=0; i<findUp.length; i++) // Find next occurence for each string
            if (done[i]!==-1) { // Key still alive

                // Never search for the word/char or is over?
                if (done[i] === null || done[i] < pos) {
                    aux = sUp.indexOf(findUp[i], pos);
                    done[i] = aux;  // Save the next occurrence
                }
                else
                    aux = done[i]   // Restore the position of last search

                if (aux < prox && aux !== -1) { // If next occurrence is minimum
                    winner = i; // Save it
                    prox = aux;
                }
        } // Not done

        if (winner === -1) { // No matches forward
            r += s.slice(pos);
            break;
        } // No winner

        // Found the character or string key in the target

        i = winner;  // Restore the winner
        r += s.slice(pos, prox); // Update piece before the match

        // Append the replacement in target
        if (! destDel)
            r += repl[destOne ? 0 : i];
        pos = prox + (isString ? 1 : findUp[i].length); // Go after match
    }  // Loop

    return r; // Return the resulting string
}
```

The documentation is below:

> ```
>  replaceAll
>
>  Syntax
>  ======
>
>       replaceAll(s, find, [repl, caseOff, byChar)
>
>  Parameters
>  ==========
>
>    "s" is a string target of replacement.
>    "find" can be a string or array of strings.
>    "repl" should be the same type than "find" or empty
>
>   If "find" is a string, it is a simple replacement for
>     all "find" occurrences in "s" by string "repl"
>
>   If "find" is an array, it will replaced each string in "find"
>     that occurs in "s" for corresponding string in "repl" array.
>   The replace specs are independent: A replacement part cannot
>   be replaced again.
>
>
>   If "repl" is empty all "find" occurrences in "s" will be deleted.
>   If "repl" has only one character or element,
>       all occurrences in "s" will be replaced for that one.
>
>   "caseOff" is true if replacement is case insensitive
>        (default is FALSE)
>
>   "byChar" is true when replacement is based on set of characters.
>   Default is false
>
>   If "byChar", it will be replaced in "s" all characters in "find"
>   set of characters for corresponding character in "repl"
>   set of characters
>
>  Return
>  ======
>
>   The function returns the new string after the replacement.
> ```

To be fair, I ran the [benchmark](http://jsben.ch/kdv27) with no parameter test.

Here is my test set, using Node.js:

```
function l() {
    return console.log.apply(null, arguments);
}

var k = 0;
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      ["ri", "nea"], ["do", "fa"]));  // 1
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      ["ri", "nea"], ["do"])); // 2
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      ["ri", "nea"])); // 3
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
     "aeiou", "", "", true)); // 4
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      "aeiou", "a", "", true)); // 5
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      "aeiou", "uoiea", "", true)); // 6
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      "aeiou", "uoi", "", true)); // 7
l(++k, replaceAll("banana is a ripe fruit harvested near the river",
      ["ri", "nea"], ["do", "fa", "leg"])); // 8
l(++k, replaceAll("BANANA IS A RIPE FRUIT HARVESTED NEAR THE RIVER",
      ["ri", "nea"], ["do", "fa"])); // 9
l(++k, replaceAll("BANANA IS A RIPE FRUIT HARVESTED NEAR THE RIVER",
      ["ri", "nea"], ["do", "fa"], true)); // 10
return;
```

And the results:

> 1 'banana is a dope fruit harvested far the dover' 
> 2 'banana is a dope fruit harvested dor the dover' 
> 3 'banana is a pe fruit harvested r the ver' 
> 4 'bnn s  rp frt hrvstd nr th rvr' 
> 5 'banana as a rapa fraat harvastad naar tha ravar' 
> 6 'bununu is u ripo frait hurvostod nour tho rivor' 
> 7 false 
> 8 false 
> 9 'BANANA IS A RIPE FRUIT HARVESTED NEAR THE RIVER' 
> 10 'BANANA IS A doPE FRUIT HARVESTED faR THE doVER'

Comment: Downvoted because using this much code to achieve something so basic feels overkill to me.

Comment: It's matter of opinion. For me It's a powerhouse and fast function. I've used for years. One cannot do it on fewer lines. For those who just want to replace chars and pieces in strings without worrying about escape characters from regular expressions, it might be a good choice.
The number of lines does not matter much, since it works is a tested black box

Comment: I like how the function deal with array inputs, same as method of [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) of PHP, but: 1. The function "caseOff" will not work while inputs be Strings. - 2. The benchmark absolutely and logically look not fair, When you define a function as prototype and redefine this and comment part of your code and also use just string inputs, the result is not fair. The fair can be this : https://jsben.ch/38Gj1 (Much different in results)

Answer (score 3):

In November 2019, a new feature is added to the JavaScript, `string.prototype.replaceAll()`.

Currently it's only supported with [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), but maybe in the future it can be implemented in all the browsers. For more information, [read here](https://v8.dev/features/string-replaceall).

Comment: Wow, javascript is finally adding what Java 1.0 had in 1995. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code with prototype:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
    var str = this;
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"), 'g'), replace);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    var $r="";
    while($r!=str){ 
        $r = str;
        str = str.replace(find, replace);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: if the replacement contains the "find" youi will have an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
var replaced_str = str.split('abc').join('');
console.log(replaced_str);
```

Comment: Like many previous answers. What is different?

Comment: Split and join is a great way to do `replaceAll` for two reasons: 1- Availability for `String.prototype.replaceAll` depends on the NodeJS version you're using. 2- If the searched value for replacement contains characters, using `replace` with regex global flag becomes harder.

Answer (score 2):

This solution combines some previous answers and conforms somewhat better to the proposed August 2020 standard solution. This solution is still viable for me in September 2020, as `String.replaceAll` is not available in the Node.js binary I am using.

---

`RegExp.escape` is a separate issue to deal with, but it is important here, because the official proposed solution will automatically escape `string`-based `find` input. This `String.replaceAll` polyfill would not without the `RegExp.escape` logic.

I have added an answer which doesn't polyfill `RegExp.Escape`, in the case that you don't want that.

---

If you pass a regular expression to `find`, you ***must*** include `g` as a flag. This [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) won't provide a nice TypeError for you and will cause you a major bad time.

If you need exact standards conformance, for an application which is rigorously relying on the standard implementation, then I suggest using [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) or some other tool to get you the 'right answer' every time instead of Stack Overflow. That way you won't have any surprises.

---

Code:

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(RegExp, 'escape')) {
  RegExp.escape = function(string) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
    // https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape/issues/37
    return string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
  };
}

if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(String, 'replaceAll')) {
  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll
    // If you pass a RegExp to 'find', you _MUST_ include 'g' as a flag.
    // TypeError: "replaceAll must be called with a global RegExp" not included, will silently cause significant errors. _MUST_ include 'g' as a flag for RegExp.
    // String parameters to 'find' do not require special handling.
    // Does not conform to "special replacement patterns" when "Specifying a string as a parameter" for replace
    // Does not conform to "Specifying a function as a parameter" for replace
    return this.replace(
          Object.prototype.toString.call(find) == '[object RegExp]' ?
            find :
            new RegExp(RegExp.escape(find), 'g'),
          replace
        );
  }
}
```

Code, Minified:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(RegExp,"escape")||(RegExp.escape=function(e){return e.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,"\\$&")}),Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(String,"replaceAll")||(String.prototype.replaceAll=function(e,t){return this.replace("[object RegExp]"==Object.prototype.toString.call(e)?e:new RegExp(RegExp.escape(e),"g"),t)});
```

---

Example:

```
console.log(
  't*.STVAL'
    .replaceAll(
      new RegExp(RegExp.escape('T*.ST'), 'ig'),
      'TEST'
    )
);

console.log(
  't*.STVAL'
    .replaceAll(
      't*.ST',
      'TEST'
    );
);
```

---

Code without `RegExp.Escape`:

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(String, 'replaceAll')) {
  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll
    // If you pass a RegExp to 'find', you _MUST_ include 'g' as a flag.
    // TypeError: "replaceAll must be called with a global RegExp" not included, will silently cause significant errors. _MUST_ include 'g' as a flag for RegExp.
    // String parameters to 'find' do not require special handling.
    // Does not conform to "special replacement patterns" when "Specifying a string as a parameter" for replace
    // Does not conform to "Specifying a function as a parameter" for replace
    return this.replace(
          Object.prototype.toString.call(find) == '[object RegExp]' ?
            find :
            new RegExp(find.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'),
          replace
        );
  }
}
```

Code without `RegExp.Escape`, Minified:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(String,"replaceAll")||(String.prototype.replaceAll=function(e,t){return this.replace("[object RegExp]"==Object.prototype.toString.call(e)?e:new RegExp(e.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,"\\$&"),"g"),t)});
```

Comment: RegExp.Escape was based on my answer linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838890/5979634

Comment: The `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(String, 'replaceAll')` will return **false** anyway, because it owned by `String.prototype` So it should be like: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(String.prototype, 'replaceAll')`

Comment: MMMahdy-PAPION is right, but in addition it would be simpler and more transparent to simply check for `String.prototype.hasOwnProperty('replaceAll')`

Answer (score 1):

For **unique** replaceable values

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search_array, replacement_array) {
  //
  var target = this;
  //
  search_array.forEach(function(substr, index) {
    if (typeof replacement_array[index] != "undefined") {
      target = target.replace(new RegExp(substr, 'g'), replacement_array[index])
    }
  });
  //
  return target;
};

//  Use:
var replacedString = "This topic commented on :year. Talking :question.".replaceAll([':year', ':question'], ['2018', 'How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript']);
//
console.log(replacedString);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work if words share the same letters.
Example : var test = "Groups_4_Questions_0__Options_0_Wording".replaceAll([4, 0, 0], [100, 200, 300])

Comment: Not meant for it. Only for unique replaceable values.

Comment: this is useless then in most case

Answer (score 1):

The best solution, in order to replace any character we use the `indexOf()`, `includes()`, and `substring()` functions to replace the matched string with the provided string in the current string.

- The [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function is to find the `n`<sup>th</sup> match index position.
- The [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.
- [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function is to get the parts of String(`preceding`,`exceding`). Add the replace String in-between these parts to generate final return String.

The following function allows to use any character.

where as [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) will not allow some special character like `**` and some characters need to be escaped, like `$`.

```javascript
String.prototype.replaceAllMatches = function(obj) { // Obj format: { 'matchkey' : 'replaceStr' }
    var retStr = this;
    for (var x in obj) {
        //var matchArray = retStr.match(new RegExp(x, 'ig'));
        //for (var i = 0; i < matchArray.length; i++) {
        var prevIndex = retStr.indexOf(x); // matchkey = '*', replaceStr = '$*' While loop never ends.
        while (retStr.includes(x)) {
            retStr = retStr.replaceMatch(x, obj[x], 0);
            var replaceIndex = retStr.indexOf(x);
            if( replaceIndex <  prevIndex + (obj[x]).length) {
                break;
            } else {
                prevIndex = replaceIndex;
            }
        }
    }
    return retStr;
};
String.prototype.replaceMatch = function(matchkey, replaceStr, matchIndex) {
    var retStr = this, repeatedIndex = 0;
    //var matchArray = retStr.match(new RegExp(matchkey, 'ig'));
    //for (var x = 0; x < matchArray.length; x++) {
    for (var x = 0; (matchkey != null) && (retStr.indexOf(matchkey) > -1); x++) {
        if (repeatedIndex == 0 && x == 0) {
            repeatedIndex = retStr.indexOf(matchkey);
        } else { // matchIndex > 0
            repeatedIndex = retStr.indexOf(matchkey, repeatedIndex + 1);
        }
        if (x == matchIndex) {
            retStr = retStr.substring(0, repeatedIndex) + replaceStr + retStr.substring(repeatedIndex + (matchkey.length));
            matchkey = null; // To break the loop.
        }
    }
    return retStr;
};
```

---

We can also use the regular expression object for matching text with a pattern. The following are functions which will use the regular expression object.

You will get SyntaxError when you are using an *invalid* regular expression pattern like `'**'`.

- The [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function is used to replace the specified String with the given String.
- The [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function is to find how many time the string is repeated.
- The [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

```javascript
String.prototype.replaceAllRegexMatches = function(obj) { // Obj format: { 'matchkey' : 'replaceStr' }
    var retStr = this;
    for (var x in obj) {
        retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'ig'), obj[x]);
    }
    return retStr;
};
```

> Note that regular expressions are written without quotes.

---

Examples to use the above functions:

```javascript
var str = "yash yas $dfdas.**";
console.log('String: ', str);

// No need to escape any special character
console.log('Index matched replace: ', str.replaceMatch('as', '*', 2));
console.log('Index Matched replace: ', str.replaceMatch('y', '~', 1));
console.log('All Matched replace: ', str.replaceAllMatches({'as': '**', 'y':'Y', '$':'-'}));
console.log('All Matched replace : ', str.replaceAllMatches({'**': '~~', '$':'&$&', '&':'%', '~':'>'}));

// You need to escape some special Characters
console.log('REGEX all matched replace: ', str.replaceAllRegexMatches({'as' : '**', 'y':'Y', '\\$':'-'}));
```

Result:

```
String:  yash yas $dfdas.**
Index Matched replace:  yash yas $dfd*.**
Index Matched replace:  yash ~as $dfdas.**

All Matched replace:  Y**h Y** -dfd**.**
All Matched replace:  yash yas %$%dfdas.>>

REGEX All Matched replace:  Y**h Y** -dfd**.**
```

---

Comment: In your loop you are repeatedly replacing in a string. This creates a new string on each iteration of the loop which for long strings will cost a lot of performance.

Regex already have support to do all replaces in one go which is much faster as it will use tricks to avoid creating multiple new strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myName = 'r//i//n//o//l////d';
var myValidName = myName.replace(new RegExp('\//', 'g'), ''); > // rinold
console.log(myValidName);

var myPetName = 'manidog';
var renameManiToJack = myPetName.replace(new RegExp('mani', 'g'), 'jack'); > // jackdog
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without Regex, but you need to be careful if the replacement text contains the search text.

e.g.

```
replaceAll("nihIaohi", "hI", "hIcIaO", true)
```

So here is a proper variant of replaceAll, including string-prototype:

```
function replaceAll(str, find, newToken, ignoreCase)
{
    let i = -1;

    if (!str)
    {
        // Instead of throwing, act as COALESCE if find == null/empty and str == null
        if ((str == null) && (find == null))
            return newToken;

        return str;
    }

    if (!find) // sanity check 
        return str;

    ignoreCase = ignoreCase || false;
    find = ignoreCase ? find.toLowerCase() : find;

    while ((
        i = (ignoreCase ? str.toLowerCase() : str).indexOf(
            find, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
        )) !== -1
    )
    {
        str = str.substring(0, i) +
            newToken +
            str.substring(i + find.length);
    } // Whend 

    return str;
}
```

Or, if you want to have a string-prototype function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    let str = this;

    let i = -1;

    if (!str)
    {
        // Instead of throwing, act as COALESCE if find == null/empty and str == null
        if ((str == null) && (find == null))
            return newToken;

        return str;
    }

    if (!find) // sanity check 
        return str;

    ignoreCase = ignoreCase || false;
    find = ignoreCase ? find.toLowerCase() : find;

    while ((
        i = (ignoreCase ? str.toLowerCase() : str).indexOf(
            find, i >= 0 ? i + newToken.length : 0
        )) !== -1
    )
    {
        str = str.substring(0, i) +
            newToken +
            str.substring(i + find.length);
    } // Whend 

    return str;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v85, Chrome now supports `String.prototype.replaceAll` natively. Note this outperform all other proposed solutions and should be used once majorly supported.

Feature status:
https://chromestatus.com/feature/6040389083463680

```js
var s = "hello hello world";
s = s.replaceAll("hello", ""); // s is now "world"
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my solution, based on some of the functional features of last versions of JavaScript:

```
   var str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";

   var result = str.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => {
      return b == 'abc' ? a : a + ' ' + b;   })

  console.warn(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution -

```js
let str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";

str = str.split(" ");
str = str.filter((ele, key)=> ele!=="abc")
str = str.join(" ")
```

Or simply -

```js
str = str.split(" ").filter((ele, key) => ele != "abc").join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc"

str.split(' ').join().replace(/abc/g,'').replace(/,/g, ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the function below to this performance test page in the "library" section:

https://jsben.ch/LFfWA

```
function _replace(t, s, r){
    var i = t.indexOf(s);
    if (i == -1) return t;
    return t.slice(0, i) + r + _replace(t.slice(i + s.length, t.length), s,r);
}
```

..and put this in as the test:

```
var replaced = _replace(testString, 'abc', '123');
```

.. and that function performs about 34% faster for me than split or regex. The idea / hope was to end up pasting smaller and smaller pieces of the string onto the stack and then building the entire result by unrolling the stack, thereby minimizing extra string copies and extra searches through the same string data and hopefully optimizing use of the CPU cache.

Part of the thought was that if the string isn't too big, it may end up in the CPU cache; passing it and pasting pieces of it puts those bits into the cache, and then the searching can operate entirely using CPU cached data. Now whether or not that's actually what ends up happening I'm sure is entirely JavaScript implementation-dependent.

This isn't as fast as possible, but it's as fast as I could manage without mutable strings. Arrays in JavaScript probably have a pointer for each element, so, a solution involving a lot of array elements is not likely to be as CPU cache friendly as this.

Comment: Re *"performs about 34% faster"*: What was it tested on? Browser, JavaScript runtime, hardware, operating system, etc. All with versions and specifications (e.g. clock speed, CPU type, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way

const str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
const result = str.split('abc').join('');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat until you have replaced them all:

```
const regex = /^>.*/im;
while (regex.test(cadena)) {
    cadena = cadena.replace(regex, '*');
}
```

Comment: This approach will replace occurrences which only appear after replacing. E.g. when replacing all occurrences of `"bc"` by `"b"`, then given the input string `"abcc"` should produce the output `"abc"`, but your approach will produce `"ab"`.

Comment: This simple script, as Sebastian says, also removes the results that match the expression. This has its good and bad sides. The bad news has already been told by him. The good news is that it is very useful for removing JS tags in XSS and JavaScript Inject attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I have read this question and answers, but I didn't find an appropriate solution for me. Although the answers are quite useful, I decided to create my own solution from scratch. The problems about this kind of replacing are:

- Often it's not enough to simply find a string which matches any upper- or lower case. E.g., for search results I need to **replace it with the same case**.
- If I deal with innerHTML, I can easily damage HTML tags (e.g., an occurrence of **hr** in the **href** attribute).
- The [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method is too fresh for many use cases, and it doesn't solve all the issues.

So, I was writing functions to highlight search results in a table, where table data cells may have links inside, as well as other HTML tags. And these links were intended to be kept, so innerText was not enough.

The solution I decided to provide for everyone with the same issues. Surely, you can use it not only for tables, but for any elements. Here is the code:

```
/* Iterate over table data cells to insert a highlight tag */
function highlightSearchResults(textFilter) {
  textFilter = textFilter.toLowerCase().replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
  let tds;
  tb = document.getElementById('sometable'); //root element where to search
  if (tb) {
    tds = tb.getElementsByTagName("td"); //sub-elements where to make replacements
  }
  if (textFilter && tds) {
    for (td of tds) {
      //specify your span class or whatever you need before and after
      td.innerHTML = insertCaseInsensitive(td.innerHTML, textFilter, '<span class="highlight">', '</span>');
    }
  }
}

/* Insert a highlight tag */
function insertCaseInsensitive(srcStr, lowerCaseFilter, before, after) {
  let lowStr = srcStr.toLowerCase();
  let flen = lowerCaseFilter.length;
  let i = -1;
  while ((i = lowStr.indexOf(lowerCaseFilter, i + 1)) != -1) {
    if (insideTag(i, srcStr)) continue;
    srcStr = srcStr.slice(0, i) + before + srcStr.slice(i, i+flen) + after + srcStr.slice(i+flen);
    lowStr = srcStr.toLowerCase();
    i += before.length + after.length;
  }
  return srcStr;
}

/* Check if an ocurrence is inside any tag by index */
function insideTag(si, s) {
  let ahead = false;
  let back = false;
  for (let i = si; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == "<") {
      break;
    }
    if (s[i] == ">") {
      ahead = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (let i = si; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (s[i] == ">") {
      break;
    }
    if (s[i] == "<") {
      back = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return (ahead && back);
}
```

Comment: Related: [How can I dynamically highlight strings on a web page?](/a/32167527/4642212), [Find and replace specific text characters across a document with JS](/a/41886794/4642212). Both links are to my answers which go into quite a bit of depth as to how to replace text content in a document.

Comment: Oh, those answers are more related to highlighting! However, I only found this replacing-related thread looking for some replacing solutions. Now I tried those functions: if I see correctly they do not highlight in a case-insensitive way, what i mean is: if phrases 'Text' or 'TEXT' (or even 'TexT', 'tExT', etc.) found, they should be highlighted as they are, without converting to lowercase/uppercase. The good thing about your code snippets that they work through the entire document and a ready-to-use solutions. These my functions should be adapted for one's needs and I think it's easy enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (sfind, sreplace) {
    var str = this;

    while (str.indexOf(sfind) > -1) {
        str = str.replace(sfind, sreplace);
    }

    return str;
};
```

Comment: [Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Comment: if the replacement contains the "find" youi will have an infinite loop

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

Example data:

```
var text = "heloo,hai,hei"

text = text.replace(/[,]+/g, '')
```

or

```
text.forEach((value) => {
  hasil = hasil.replace(',', '')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn’t the best way to do this, but you can try this:

```
var annoyingString = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";

while (annoyingString.includes("abc")) {
    annoyingString = annoyingString.replace("abc", "")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

All the answers are accepted, and you can do this by many ways. One of the trick to do this is this:

```js
const str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";

const compare = "abc";
arrayStr = str.split(" ");
arrayStr.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (element == compare) {
    arrayStr.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
const newString = arrayStr.join(" ");
console.log(newString);
```