# Match a string to a value in an array and return the id of that value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have the following array in JavaScript:

```
var skins = new Array('Light', 'Medium', 'Dark');
```

How would I go about checking to see what ID in that array (0, 1, or 2) has a matching value to a string I give it.  So for example, if I look at a string of 'Medium', I should be returned the ID 1.

Comment: Take a look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137481#1137481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.indexOf](http://eveloper.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var index = skins.indexOf('Medium'); // 1
```

This function has been introduced in [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6), but you can include it for compatibility with old browsers.

Here is the algorithm used by Firefox:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++) {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.lastIndex= function(what){
 var L= this.length;
 while(L){
  if(this[--L]=== what) return L;
 }
 return -1;
}

Array.prototype.firstIndex= function(what){
 var i=0, L= this.length;
 while(i<L){
  if(this[i]=== what) return i;
  ++i;
 }
 return -1;
}
```