# Can a datatable cell contains a datatable?

Tags: c#, ado.net

If not which structure should I use ?

Comment: As you can see from the answers, people are having a hard time trying to understand what you mean. Please elaborate on your queston. Pseudo-code showing what you are trying to do will help.

Comment: @Alfred I totally agree with you and it really bothers me when people don't elaborate their questions and wait for others to understand their assumptions. Come on we are not fortunetellers, aren't we.

Comment: I want nested dataTables. Will have to read the answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can add a new `DataTable` to a `DataTable` cell.
Simple Example:

Define the primary table with one cell type `DataTable`:

```
DataTable people = new DataTable();
people.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
people.Columns.Add("Friends", typeof(DataTable));
```

Define the sub table:

```
DataTable friends = new DataTable();
friends.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
friends.Columns.Add("Desire", typeof(string));
```

Add some data to the sub table:

```
friends.Rows.Add("Scarecrow", "brain");
friends.Rows.Add("Tin Woodman", "heart");
friends.Rows.Add("Cowardly Lion", "courage");
```

And finally, add a row to the primary table:

```
people.Rows.Add("Dorothy", friends);
```

To get the sub table from the primary table you need to cast the object as `DataTable`:

```
DataTable output = (DataTable)people.Rows[0]["Friends"];
```

Answer (score 3):

DataSet can contain several datatables with different schemas. You can store your second datatable in a second table and reference it to your row at first table.

Also you can use [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx) and [ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx) methods to store your datatable into a data cell.

[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx): Take a look at [that answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx).     [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx): [What are useful JavaScript methods that extends built-in objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137481#1137481)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to persist it to a database, you would be better served looking at a foreign-key / `DataRelation`. If you *really* want more structured data in a cell, then perhaps something like xml, or some other serialization format.

Comment: (or use an auxiliary key-value table instead)

Answer (score 0):

According to what I infer from your question you can say something like this :

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
DataTable dtable = dr[0].Table
```

MSDN : DataRow's DataTable Property : Gets the  DataTable for which this row has a schema.

Example and Explanation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table.aspx

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe the OP is referring to *nested* data, rather than getting back to the table from a row.

Comment: That's what I know :) you can simply find the related information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table.aspx

Comment: -1: you cannot write `DataRow dr = new DataRow()`. I believe the ctor for DataRow is internal to .Net and can only be accessed by the likes of `DataTable.NewRow()` which returns a new `DataRow` with reference to the owning table's schema.