# Helper functions & prototype methods to replace heavy frameworks?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, helper, prototype

All frameworks aside, what are some of the common helper functions/prototype methods you use on a daily basis?

Please note I am **not** arguing against frameworks. I've simply found that the majority of what I do on a daily basis can, most often, be done with a few dozen Array, String and Element.prototype methods. With the addition of a few helper functions like $ (getElementsById) and $$$ (getElementsByClass), I am able to satisfy some of the core benefits, however basic, of a much heavier framework.

If you were to collect a small library of basic methods and functions to replace the core functionality of some of the popular frameworks, what would they be?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/what-are-useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects

Comment: I don't think I could live without all the power of jQuery's $("selector") method for finding elements...

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery I would most miss selector functions, events, `$.map`, `$.each`, (my own) `$.inject`, `css`, `data`, and `val`.

Not sure much that's interesting is left after that, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) is very usefull if you are lack of JQuery. Eg. if you are working on VueJs project. Another more serious one is [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#readme)