# Convert UNIX Time to mm/dd/yy hh:mm (24 hour) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been using

```
timeStamp = new Date(unixTime*1000);
document.write(timeStamp.toString());
```

And it will output for example:

Tue Jul 6 08:47:00 CDT 2010
//24 hour time

Screen real estate is prime, so I would like to take up less space with the date and output:

mm/dd/yy hh:mm
//also 24 hour time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add an extra method to the `Date` object, so you can reuse it as much as you want. First, we need to define a helper function, [`String.padLeft`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/what-are-useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137468#1137468):

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (length, character) { 
    return new Array(length - this.length + 1).join(character || ' ') + this; 
};
```

After this, we define `Date.toFormattedString`:

```
Date.prototype.toFormattedString = function () {
    return [String(this.getMonth()+1).padLeft(2, '0'),
            String(this.getDate()).padLeft(2, '0'),
            String(this.getFullYear()).substr(2, 2)].join("/") + " " +
           [String(this.getHours()).padLeft(2, '0'),
            String(this.getMinutes()).padLeft(2, '0')].join(":");
};
```

Now you can simply use this method like any other method of the `Date` object:

```
var timeStamp = new Date(unixTime*1000);
document.write(timeStamp.toFormattedString());
```

But please bear in mind that this kind of formatting can be confusing. E.g., when issuing

```
new Date().toFormattedString()
```

the function returns `07/06/10 22:05` at the moment. For me, this is more like June 7th than July 6th.

**EDIT:** This only works if the year can be represented using a four-digit number. After December 31st, 9999, this will malfunction and you'll have to adjust the code.

Comment: This will break after Y10K. There, I said it.

Comment: After December 31st, 9999 developer himself malfunction :D

Comment: If my options haven't vested by then, screw 'em.

Comment: Instead of `substr(2, 2)`, just use `slice(-2)`, and that will work until the end of the world. :P

Comment: It is bad idea to modify standard objects. Just think about each library trying to change `Date` in they own way (and the conflict when using several of them). Just don't do it!