# How do I format a date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

How do I format a Javascript `Date` object as a string? (Preferably in the format: `10-Aug-2010`)

Comment: As usual: beware THE MONTH is ZERO-INDEXED ! So January is zero not one...

Comment: Also beware, `myDate.getDay()` doesn't return the day of week, but the **location of the weekday** related to the week. `myDate.getDate()` returns the **current weekday**.

Comment: You can use `toLocaleDateString `

Comment: @onmyway you actually can't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat

Comment: If you’re looking how to parse a string to a Date object, see [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](/q/5619202/4642212).

Comment: 86 answers. 84 are hard-coded to just this specific format. I'm over 12 years late, but see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800084/1045881) for a solution for all date format strings you might ever need, without needing an external library.

Comment: 13 years later we have `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. See [this Stackblitz-project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5wqvwc?file=script.js)

Comment: FWIW: [es-date-fiddler](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Answer (score 1737, accepted):

For custom-delimited date formats, you have to pull out the date (or time)
components from a [`DateTimeFormat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) object (which is part of the
[ECMAScript Internationalization API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)), and then manually create a string
with the delimiters you want.

To do this, you can use [`DateTimeFormat#formatToParts`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts). You could
destructure the array, but that is not ideal, as the array output depends on the
locale:

```js
{ // example 1
   let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en');
   let example = formatter.formatToParts();
   console.log(example);
}
{ // example 2
   let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('hi');
   let example = formatter.formatToParts();
   console.log(example);
}
```

Better would be to map a format array to resultant strings:

```js
function join(date, options, separator) {
   function format(option) {
      let formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', option);
      return formatter.format(date);
   }
   return options.map(format).join(separator);
}

let options = [{day: 'numeric'}, {month: 'short'}, {year: 'numeric'}];
let joined = join(new Date, options, '-');
console.log(joined);
```

You can also pull out the parts of a `DateTimeFormat` one-by-one using
[`DateTimeFormat#format`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format), but note that when using this method, as of March
2020, there is [a bug](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60544534#60545316) in the ECMAScript implementation when it comes to
leading zeros on minutes and seconds (this bug is circumvented by the approach
above).

```js
let date = new Date(2010, 7, 5);
let year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(date);
let month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(date);
let day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(date);
console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year}`);
```

When working with dates and times, it is usually worth using a library (eg. [luxon](//moment.github.io/luxon), [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), [<del>moment.js</del> is not recommended for new projects](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/)) because of the many hidden complexities of the field.

Note that the ECMAScript Internationalization API, used in the solutions above
is not supported [in IE10](//caniuse.com#search=datetimeformat) ([0.03%](//gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-market-share) global browser market share in Feb
2020).

Comment: Or extend the `Date` object, like I did at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187790/convert-unix-time-to-mm-dd-yy-hhmm-24-hour-in-javascript/3189792#3189792

Comment: this is the best answer IMHO (last snippet) because allows flexibility in any format, i.e., you don't need to seek the country code that satisfies your needs

Comment: The answer is correct, but the laziness on the variable names is really on another level. He write da instead of day. Proper variable names would be really great!

Comment: Why momentjs is not recommended for new project? I used it in the past and I remember it being very useful

Comment: @fudo While momentjs is not deprecated, their authors considered it "abandoned". They are no longer maintaining or improving the library. It's extremely large and provokes issues with popular JS Frameworks such as Angular or React, so it's being superseded by other options.

Comment: ECMAScript Internationalization API is well supported now please check https://caniuse.com/internationalization

Answer (score 3002):

If you need slightly less control over formatting than the currently accepted answer, [`Date#toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) can be used to create standard locale-specific renderings. The `locale` and `options` arguments let applications specify the language whose formatting conventions should be used, and allow some customization of the rendering.

##### Options key examples:

1. **day:** 
   The representation of the day. 
   Possible values are "numeric", "2-digit".
2. **weekday:** 
   The representation of the weekday. 
   Possible values are "narrow", "short", "long".
3. **year:** 
   The representation of the year. 
   Possible values are "numeric", "2-digit".
4. **month:** 
   The representation of the month. 
   Possible values are "numeric", "2-digit", "narrow", "short", "long".
5. **hour:** 
   The representation of the hour. 
   Possible values are "numeric", "2-digit".
6. **minute:**
   The representation of the minute. 
   Possible values are "numeric", "2-digit".
7. **second:** 
   The representation of the second. 
   Possible values are "numeric", 2-digit".
8. **hour12:** 
   The representation of time format. 
   Accepts boolean true or false

All these keys are optional.  You can change the number of options values based on your requirements, and this will also reflect the presence of each date time term.

Note: If you would only like to configure the content options, but still use the current locale, passing `null` for the first parameter will cause an error.  Use `undefined` instead.

##### For different languages:

1. **"en-US":** For American English
2. **"en-GB":** For British English
3. **"hi-IN":** For Hindi
4. **"ja-JP":** For Japanese

You can use more language options.

##### For example

```js
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var today  = new Date();

console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US")); // 9/17/2016
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)); // Saturday, September 17, 2016
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("hi-IN", options)); // शनिवार, 17 सितंबर 2016
```

You can also use the `toLocaleString()` method for the same purpose. The only difference is this function provides the time when you don't pass any options.

```
// Example
9/17/2016, 1:21:34 PM
```

##### References:

- [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)
- [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: [this](https://mdn-mixmix.hashbase.io/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat.html) says its a non standard, but [mozzilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) doesn't specify that

Comment: Seems like this answer should be the best "current" answer.  Also used the option "hour12: true" to use 12-hour vs 24-hour format.  Maybe should be added to your summary list in the answer.

Comment: `timeZoneName` option doesn't works in IE (tested in IE 11)

Comment: @Iarwa1n This answer hasn't mentioned but you can use toLocaleDateString to return only certain parts that you can then join as you wish. Check my answer below. `date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { day: 'numeric' }) 
            + "-"+ date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'short' })
            + "-" + date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { year: 'numeric' })` should give `16-Nov-2019`

Comment: It was a long long dig of following links, but I found where they're hidden @MosesSchwartz: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Comment: @KVij—that's a very inefficient way to go about formatting a date, especially considering there is a [*formatToParts* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) that returns all the parts in an array of objects.

Comment: Note the following info from the docs "To use the browser's default locale, pass an empty array."  (for the locale argument).

Comment: The fact that the current best way is a hardcoded list is something I don't really like. I would like to have a simple option to format in any given format I want to.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it is the only one that worked with a minimum of code and no external libraries

Comment: this doesnt work in typescript

Answer (score 782):

If you need to quickly format your date using plain JavaScript, use `getDate`, `getMonth + 1`, `getFullYear`, `getHours` and `getMinutes`:

```
var d = new Date();

var datestring = d.getDate()  + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() + " " +
d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

// 16-5-2015 9:50
```

Or, if you need it to be padded with zeros:

```
var datestring = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
    d.getFullYear() + " " + ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

// 16-05-2015 09:50
```

Comment: you can also pad zeros with `.toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: @BennyJobigan It should be mentioned that `String.padStart()` is only available from ECMAScript 2017.

Comment: using ES6 template literals and a helper function ```let pad = v => `0${v}`.slice(-2);``` the padded version can be simplified to this: ```let datestring = `${d.getFullYear()}-${pad(d.getMonth() + 1)}-${pad(d.getDate())}_${pad(d.getHours())}-${pad(d.getMinutes())}`;```

Answer (score 703):

Use the [date.format library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format):

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

returns:

```
Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
```

[dateformat on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat)

http://jsfiddle.net/phZr7/1/

Comment: His code for "L" for cantiseconds is wrong, he should remove "L > 99 ?" part... Other than that, it's pretty neat, if not too well localizable.

Comment: This solution is also available as an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of importing a external dependency, I'd recommend using moment.js. It can do this type of date formatting: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ And it has much more functionality.

Comment: timezone also works well for dateformat compared to [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) in IE

Comment: While the inclusion of Moment.js was fine a few years ago, work on it has since been discontinued: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 584):

Well, what I wanted was to convert today's date to a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) friendly date string like `2012-06-23`, and to use that string as a parameter in one of my queries. The simple solution I've found is this:

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

Keep in mind that the above solution does **not** take into account your *timezone* offset.

You might consider using this function instead:

```js
function toJSONLocal (date) {
    var local = new Date(date);
    local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
    return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
}
```

This will give you the correct date in case you are executing this code around the start/end of the day.

```js
var date = new Date();

function toLocal(date) {
  var local = new Date(date);
  local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
  return local.toJSON();
}

function toJSONLocal(date) {
  var local = new Date(date);
  local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
  return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
}

// check out your devtools console
console.log(date.toJSON());
console.log(date.toISOString());
console.log(toLocal(date));

console.log(toJSONLocal(date));
```

- [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)
- [Date.toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)
- [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [External example](http://jsfiddle.net/simo/sapuhzmm/)

Comment: You can do `new Date(date + " UTC")` to trick the timezone, and you can eliminate the setMinutes line. Man, javascript is dirty

Comment: Y10K compatible version: `var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,-14)` :)

Comment: Or like this `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]`

Comment: Y10K compatible and when browser doesn't returns timezone: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-ca-iso8601').format(new Date())` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348431/best-way-to-remove-edt-from-a-date-returned-via-javascript-with-tolocalestring

Comment: `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16).replace('T',' ')` to include time

Comment: Just commenting that the lack of timezone is not some minor inconvenience "around the start/end of the day". In Australia, for instance, the date may be wrong until about 11AM - nearly half the day!

Comment: @slang True, but the lifespan of my program isn't Y10K compatible either :). I'll bank on there being AI to sort this out by then.

Comment: This is simply a bad idea. `toISOString` will change the date to UTC so it could be +/- 1 day at given time of day.

Comment: "new Date().toISOString()" can be used for getting a fixed format. And then what do you want...

Answer (score 427):

### Custom formatting function:

For fixed formats, a simple function make the job. The following example generates the international format YYYY-MM-DD:

```js
function dateToYMD(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1; //Month from 0 to 11
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + y + '-' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
}

console.log(dateToYMD(new Date(2017,10,5))); // Nov 5
```

The OP format may be generated like:

```js
function dateToYMD(date) {
    var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = strArray[date.getMonth()];
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y;
}
console.log(dateToYMD(new Date(2017,10,5))); // Nov 5
```

Note: It is, however, usually not a good idea to extend the JavaScript standard libraries (e.g. by adding this function to the prototype of Date).

A more advanced function could generate configurable output based on a format parameter.

If to write a formatting function is too long, there are plenty of libraries around which does it. Some other answers already enumerate them. But increasing dependencies also has it counter-part.

### Standard ECMAScript formatting functions:

Since more recent versions of ECMAScript, the `Date` class has some specific formatting functions:

> **toDateString**: Implementation dependent, show only the date.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.todatestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toDateString(); // e.g. "Fri Nov 11 2016"
> ```

---

> **toISOString**: Show ISO 8601 date and time.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring
>
> ```
> new Date().toISOString(); // e.g. "2016-11-21T08:00:00.000Z"
> ```

---

> **toJSON**: Stringifier for JSON.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tojson
>
> ```
> new Date().toJSON(); // e.g. "2016-11-21T08:00:00.000Z"
> ```

---

> **toLocaleDateString**: Implementation dependent, a date in locale format.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toLocaleDateString(); // e.g. "21/11/2016"
> ```

---

> **toLocaleString**: Implementation dependent, a date&time in locale format.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toLocaleString(); // e.g. "21/11/2016, 08:00:00 AM"
> ```

---

> **toLocaleTimeString**: Implementation dependent, a time in locale format.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // e.g. "08:00:00 AM"
> ```

---

> **toString**: Generic toString for Date.
>
> https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring
>
> ```
> new Date().toString(); // e.g. "Fri Nov 21 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
> ```

Note: it is possible to generate custom output out of those formatting >

> ```
> new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); //return YYYY-MM-DD
> ```

Examples snippets:

```js
console.log("1) "+  new Date().toDateString());
console.log("2) "+  new Date().toISOString());
console.log("3) "+  new Date().toJSON());
console.log("4) "+  new Date().toLocaleDateString());
console.log("5) "+  new Date().toLocaleString());
console.log("6) "+  new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
console.log("7) "+  new Date().toString());
console.log("8) "+  new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

### Specifying the locale for standard functions:

Some of the standard functions listed above are dependent on the locale:

- `toLocaleDateString()`
- `toLocaleTimeString()`
- `toLocalString()`

This is because different cultures make uses of different formats, and express their date or time in different ways.
The function by default will return the format configured on the device it runs, but this can be specified by setting the arguments (ECMA-402).

```
toLocaleDateString([locales[, options]])
toLocaleTimeString([locales[, options]])
toLocaleString([locales[, options]])
//e.g. toLocaleDateString('ko-KR');
```

The `option` second parameter, allow for configuring more specific format inside the selected locale. For instance, the month can be show as full-text or abreviation.

```
toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: 'short' })
toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: 'long' })
```

Examples snippets:

```js
console.log("1) "+  new Date().toLocaleString('en-US'));
console.log("2) "+  new Date().toLocaleString('ko-KR'));
console.log("3) "+  new Date().toLocaleString('de-CH'));

console.log("4) "+  new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { hour12: false }));
console.log("5) "+  new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { hour12: true }));
```

Some good practices regarding locales:

- Most people don't like their dates to appear in a foreigner format, consequently, keep the default locale whenever possible (over setting 'en-US' everywhere).
- Implementing conversion from/to UTC can be challenging (considering DST, time-zone not multiple of 1 hour, etc.). Use a well-tested library when possible.
- Don't assume the locale correlate to a country: several countries have many of them (Canada, India, etc.)
- Avoid detecting the locale through non-standard ways. Here you can read about the multiple pitfalls: detecting the keyboard layout, detecting the locale by the geographic location, etc..

Comment: Nicely listed the supported parameters of `Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor` are listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Comment: `.toJSON()` uses `.toIsoString()` under the hood (according to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON#description)). And **one needs to be aware** that ISO conversions convert to another time zone, which can change the date portion (see other comments). Also, seems the OP wants to convert to an Oracle (etc.) "locale/culture", not a human one...

Comment: The answer is sufficiently general to be applied for computer-representation AND for human-readable. I would also reiterate that UTC conversion can have tricky effects when DST is switched (twice a year), thus making any bug difficult to detect.

Answer (score 190):

If you are **already using jQuery UI** in your project you could do it this way:

```
var formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate("M d, yy", new Date("2014-07-08T09:02:21.377"));

// formatted will be 'Jul 8, 2014'
```

Some datepicker date format options to play with are available [here](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html).

Answer (score 170):

> ### Note (2022-10): `toLocaleFormat` has been deprecated for some time and was removed from Firefox as of version 58. See [`toLocaleFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_toLocaleFormat)

I think you can just use the **non-standard** Date method `toLocaleFormat(formatString)`

**formatString:** A format string in the same format expected by the [`strftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) function in C.

```js
    var today = new Date();
   today.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y'); // 30-Dec-2011
```

**References:**

- [`toLocaleFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_toLocaleFormat)
- [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/)

Comment: toLocaleFormat() appears to only work in Firefox. Both IE and Chrome are failing for me.

Comment: Chrome has .toLocaleString('en') method. As it seems new browser supports this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Read warning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat

Comment: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat` appears to be the replacement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: 7 years later this function still does not work in other browsers and was deprecated in Firefox
[Deprecated_toLocaleFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fehler/Deprecated_toLocaleFormat)

Comment: `toLocaleString()` should be used instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Property 'toLocaleFormat' does not exist on type 'Date'.

Comment: Deprecated as of Dec 2021

Answer (score 126):

Plain JavaScript is the best pick for small onetimers.

On the other hand, if you need more date stuff, [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is a great solution.

**For example:**

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:m:s');     // now() -> 2015-03-24 14:32:20
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 3 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 3 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 11 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 13 hours
```

Comment: important to mention: don't use `YYYY` unless you know the difference between `YYYY` and `yyyy`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter

Comment: @Domin that's specific to NSDateFormatter in iOS, as used from e.g. Objective-C or Swift. This question is about Javascript in the browser, and this answer uses MomentJS, in which `YYYY` (not `yyyy`) is the standard year and `GGGG` (not `YYYY`) is the ISO week-based year.

Answer (score 118):

In modern browsers **(*)**, you can just do this:

```
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'short',
    year : 'numeric'
}).split(' ').join('-');
```

Output if executed today (january 24ᵗʰ, 2016):

```
'24-Jan-2016'
```

---

**(*)** [**According to MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), "modern browsers" means Chrome 24+, Firefox 29+, Internet Explorer 11, Edge 12+, Opera 15+ & Safari [**nightly build**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56490/what-does-nightly-builds-mean).

Answer (score 61):

Requested format in one line - no libraries and no Date methods, just regex:

```
var d = (new Date()).toString().replace(/\S+\s(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*/,'$2-$1-$3');
// date will be formatted as "14-Oct-2015" (pass any date object in place of 'new Date()')
```

In my testing, this works reliably in the major browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE.) As @RobG pointed out, the output of Date.prototype.toString() is implementation-dependent, so for international or non-browser implementations, just test the output to be sure it works right in your JavaScript engine. You can even add some code to test the string output and make sure it's matching what you expect before you do the regex replace.

Answer (score 57):

**Packaged Solution:** [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

If you want to use a one solution to fit all, I recommend using date-fns or Luxon.

Luxon is hosted on the Moment.js website and developed by a Moment.js developer because Moment.js has limitations that the developer wanted to address but couldn't.

To install:

`npm install luxon` or `yarn add luxon` (visit link for other installation methods)

Example:

`luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2010-08-10').toFormat('yyyy-LLL-dd');`

Yields:

> 10-Aug-2010

**Manual Solution**

Using similar formatting as Moment.js, [Class DateTimeFormatter (Java)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), and [Class SimpleDateFormat (Java)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I implemented a comprehensive solution `formatDate(date, patternStr)` where the code is easy to read and modify. You can display date, time, AM/PM, etc. See code for more examples.

Example:

`formatDate(new Date(), 'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss:S')`

(`formatDate` is implemented in the code snippet below)

Yields:

> Friday, October 12, 2018 18:11:23:445

Try the code out by clicking "Run code snippet."

**Date and Time Patterns**

`yy` = 2-digit year; `yyyy` = full year

`M` = digit month; `MM` = 2-digit month; `MMM` = short month name; `MMMM` = full month name

`EEEE` = full weekday name; `EEE` = short weekday name

`d` = digit day; `dd` = 2-digit day

`h` = hours am/pm; `hh` = 2-digit hours am/pm; `H` = hours; `HH` = 2-digit hours

`m` = minutes; `mm` = 2-digit minutes; `aaa` = AM/PM

`s` = seconds; `ss` = 2-digit seconds

`S` = miliseconds

```js
var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var dayOfWeekNames = [
  "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
];
function formatDate(date, patternStr){
    if (!patternStr) {
        patternStr = 'M/d/yyyy';
    }
    var day = date.getDate(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        hour = date.getHours(),
        minute = date.getMinutes(),
        second = date.getSeconds(),
        miliseconds = date.getMilliseconds(),
        h = hour % 12,
        hh = twoDigitPad(h),
        HH = twoDigitPad(hour),
        mm = twoDigitPad(minute),
        ss = twoDigitPad(second),
        aaa = hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM',
        EEEE = dayOfWeekNames[date.getDay()],
        EEE = EEEE.substr(0, 3),
        dd = twoDigitPad(day),
        M = month + 1,
        MM = twoDigitPad(M),
        MMMM = monthNames[month],
        MMM = MMMM.substr(0, 3),
        yyyy = year + "",
        yy = yyyy.substr(2, 2)
    ;
    // checks to see if month name will be used
    patternStr = patternStr
      .replace('hh', hh).replace('h', h)
      .replace('HH', HH).replace('H', hour)
      .replace('mm', mm).replace('m', minute)
      .replace('ss', ss).replace('s', second)
      .replace('S', miliseconds)
      .replace('dd', dd).replace('d', day)
      
      .replace('EEEE', EEEE).replace('EEE', EEE)
      .replace('yyyy', yyyy)
      .replace('yy', yy)
      .replace('aaa', aaa);
    if (patternStr.indexOf('MMM') > -1) {
        patternStr = patternStr
          .replace('MMMM', MMMM)
          .replace('MMM', MMM);
    }
    else {
        patternStr = patternStr
          .replace('MM', MM)
          .replace('M', M);
    }
    return patternStr;
}
function twoDigitPad(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}
console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy')); //OP's request
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss.S aaa'));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'EEE, MMM d, yyyy HH:mm'));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'M/dd/yyyy h:mmaaa'));
```

Thank you @Gerry for bringing up Luxon.

Comment: Yes. Moment is deprecated. Please use luxon

Answer (score 51):

@Sébastien  -- alternative all browser support

```
new Date(parseInt(496407600)*1000).toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {
year: 'numeric',
month: '2-digit',
day: '2-digit'
}).replace(/\./g, '/');
```

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

---

High-order tagged template literal example based on Date.toLocaleDateString:

```
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 4, 2, 3, 23, 16, 738));
const fmt = (dt, lc = "en-US") => (str, ...expr) =>
    str.map((str, i) => str + (expr[i]?dt.toLocaleDateString(lc, expr[i]) :'')).join('')

console.log(fmt(date)`${{year: 'numeric'}}-${{month: '2-digit'}}-${{day: '2-digit'}}`);
// expected output: "2020-05-02"
```

Comment: Instead of doing .replace(), you could simply use 'en-GB' as locale. :)

Answer (score 44):

**OK**, we have got something called **Intl** which is very useful for formatting a date in JavaScript these days:

Your date as below:

```
var date = '10/8/2010';
```

And you change to Date by using new Date() like below:

```
date = new Date(date);
```

And now you can format it any way you like using a list of **locales** like below:

```
date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-AU').format(date); // Australian date format: "8/10/2010"
```

```
date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date); // USA date format: "10/8/2010"
```

```
date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-EG').format(date);  // Arabic date format: "٨‏/١٠‏/٢٠١٠"
```

If you exactly want the format you mentioned above, you can do:

```
date = new Date(Date.UTC(2010, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0));
var options = {year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric"};
date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-AU", options).format(date).replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

And the result is going to be:

```
"10-Aug-2010"
```

For more see the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) and [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) documentation.

Comment: Not supported by IE

Comment: It is but only by IE11, IE10- have been out of life way before this existed so it's understandable.

92% from caniuse, which is pretty good https://caniuse.com/#search=datetimeformat

Answer (score 37):

The `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse()`) only accepts one format as a parameter when constructing a date and that is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```js
// new Date('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ')
const date = new Date('2017-08-15')
```

**But** parsing a from a string is strongly discouraged (MDN recommends against creating date with date strings) due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

The recommended alternative would be building your Date instance directly from the numeric data like this:

```js
new Date(2017, 7, 15) // Month is zero-indexed
```

That is parsing. Now, to format your date to the string you desire you have several options that are native of the Date object (although I believe none is compliant to the format you require):

```js
date.toString()       // 'Wed Jan 23 2019 17:23:42 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)'
date.toDateString()   // 'Wed Jan 23 2019'
date.toLocaleString() // '23/01/2019, 17:23:42'
date.toGMTString()    // 'Wed, 23 Jan 2019 09:23:42 GMT'
date.toUTCString()    // 'Wed, 23 Jan 2019 09:23:42 GMT'
date.toISOString()    // '2019-01-23T09:23:42.079Z'
```

For other formatting options I'm afraid you'll have to turn to libraries such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), [day.js](https://day.js.org/) and the like.

*Credit to [Zell Liew](https://css-tricks.com/author/zellwk/) from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/) for the date formatting tips.*

Answer (score 36):

Using an ECMAScript Edition 6 (ES6/ES2015) string template:

```
let d = new Date();
let formatted = `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth() + 1}-${d.getDate()}`;
```

If you need to change the delimiters:

```
const delimiter = '/';
let formatted = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate()].join(delimiter);
```

Answer (score 25):

Here's is some code I just wrote to handle the date formatting for a project I'm working on. It mimics the PHP date formatting functionality to suit my needs. Feel free to use it, it's just extending the already existing Date() object. This may not be the most elegant solution but it's working for my needs.

```
var d = new Date(); 
d_string = d.format("m/d/Y h:i:s");

/**************************************
 * Date class extension
 * 
 */
    // Provide month names
    Date.prototype.getMonthName = function(){
        var month_names = [
                            'January',
                            'February',
                            'March',
                            'April',
                            'May',
                            'June',
                            'July',
                            'August',
                            'September',
                            'October',
                            'November',
                            'December'
                        ];

        return month_names[this.getMonth()];
    }

    // Provide month abbreviation
    Date.prototype.getMonthAbbr = function(){
        var month_abbrs = [
                            'Jan',
                            'Feb',
                            'Mar',
                            'Apr',
                            'May',
                            'Jun',
                            'Jul',
                            'Aug',
                            'Sep',
                            'Oct',
                            'Nov',
                            'Dec'
                        ];

        return month_abbrs[this.getMonth()];
    }

    // Provide full day of week name
    Date.prototype.getDayFull = function(){
        var days_full = [
                            'Sunday',
                            'Monday',
                            'Tuesday',
                            'Wednesday',
                            'Thursday',
                            'Friday',
                            'Saturday'
                        ];
        return days_full[this.getDay()];
    };

    // Provide full day of week name
    Date.prototype.getDayAbbr = function(){
        var days_abbr = [
                            'Sun',
                            'Mon',
                            'Tue',
                            'Wed',
                            'Thur',
                            'Fri',
                            'Sat'
                        ];
        return days_abbr[this.getDay()];
    };

    // Provide the day of year 1-365
    Date.prototype.getDayOfYear = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
        return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
    };

    // Provide the day suffix (st,nd,rd,th)
    Date.prototype.getDaySuffix = function() {
        var d = this.getDate();
        var sfx = ["th","st","nd","rd"];
        var val = d%100;

        return (sfx[(val-20)%10] || sfx[val] || sfx[0]);
    };

    // Provide Week of Year
    Date.prototype.getWeekOfYear = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
    } 

    // Provide if it is a leap year or not
    Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function(){
        var yr = this.getFullYear();

        if ((parseInt(yr)%4) == 0){
            if (parseInt(yr)%100 == 0){
                if (parseInt(yr)%400 != 0){
                    return false;
                }
                if (parseInt(yr)%400 == 0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (parseInt(yr)%100 != 0){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if ((parseInt(yr)%4) != 0){
            return false;
        } 
    };

    // Provide Number of Days in a given month
    Date.prototype.getMonthDayCount = function() {
        var month_day_counts = [
                                    31,
                                    this.isLeapYear() ? 29 : 28,
                                    31,
                                    30,
                                    31,
                                    30,
                                    31,
                                    31,
                                    30,
                                    31,
                                    30,
                                    31
                                ];

        return month_day_counts[this.getMonth()];
    } 

    // format provided date into this.format format
    Date.prototype.format = function(dateFormat){
        // break apart format string into array of characters
        dateFormat = dateFormat.split("");

        var date = this.getDate(),
            month = this.getMonth(),
            hours = this.getHours(),
            minutes = this.getMinutes(),
            seconds = this.getSeconds();
        // get all date properties ( based on PHP date object functionality )
        var date_props = {
            d: date < 10 ? '0'+date : date,
            D: this.getDayAbbr(),
            j: this.getDate(),
            l: this.getDayFull(),
            S: this.getDaySuffix(),
            w: this.getDay(),
            z: this.getDayOfYear(),
            W: this.getWeekOfYear(),
            F: this.getMonthName(),
            m: month < 10 ? '0'+(month+1) : month+1,
            M: this.getMonthAbbr(),
            n: month+1,
            t: this.getMonthDayCount(),
            L: this.isLeapYear() ? '1' : '0',
            Y: this.getFullYear(),
            y: this.getFullYear()+''.substring(2,4),
            a: hours > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
            A: hours > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM',
            g: hours % 12 > 0 ? hours % 12 : 12,
            G: hours > 0 ? hours : "12",
            h: hours % 12 > 0 ? hours % 12 : 12,
            H: hours,
            i: minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes,
            s: seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds           
        };

        // loop through format array of characters and add matching data else add the format character (:,/, etc.)
        var date_string = "";
        for(var i=0;i<dateFormat.length;i++){
            var f = dateFormat[i];
            if(f.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g)){
                date_string += date_props[f] ? date_props[f] : '';
            } else {
                date_string += f;
            }
        }

        return date_string;
    };
/*
 *
 * END - Date class extension
 * 
 ************************************/
```

Answer (score 23):

This may help with the problem:

```js
var d = new Date();

var options = {   
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long', 
    year: 'numeric'
};

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('en-ZA', options));
```

Answer (score 20):

A JavaScript solution without using any external libraries:

```
var now = new Date()
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
var formattedDate = now.getDate() + "-" + months[now.getMonth()] + "-" + now.getFullYear()
alert(formattedDate)
```

Answer (score 20):

A useful and flexible way for formatting the DateTimes in JavaScript is `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```
var date = new Date();
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit'};
var _resultDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options).format(date);
// The _resultDate is: "12 Oct 2017"
// Replace all spaces with - and then log it.
console.log(_resultDate.replace(/ /g,'-'));
```

Result Is:  `"12-Oct-2017"`

The date and time formats can be customized using the options argument.

The `Intl.DateTimeFormat` object is a constructor for objects that enable language sensitive date and time formatting.

Syntax

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat([locales[, options]])
Intl.DateTimeFormat.call(this[, locales[, options]])
```

**Parameters**

**locales**

Optional. A string with a BCP 47 language tag, or an array of such strings. For the general form and interpretation of the locales argument, see the Intl page. The following Unicode extension keys are allowed:

```
nu
Numbering system. Possible values include: "arab", "arabext", "bali", "beng", "deva", "fullwide", "gujr", "guru", "hanidec", "khmr", "knda", "laoo", "latn", "limb", "mlym", "mong", "mymr", "orya", "tamldec", "telu", "thai", "tibt".
ca
Calendar. Possible values include: "buddhist", "chinese", "coptic", "ethioaa", "ethiopic", "gregory", "hebrew", "indian", "islamic", "islamicc", "iso8601", "japanese", "persian", "roc".
```

**Options**

Optional. An object with some or all of the following properties:

**localeMatcher**

The locale matching algorithm to use. Possible values are `"lookup"` and `"best fit"`; the default is `"best fit"`. For information about this option, see the Intl page.

**timeZone**

The time zone to use. The only value implementations must recognize is `"UTC"`; the default is the runtime's default time zone. Implementations may also recognize the time zone names of the IANA time zone database, such as `"Asia/Shanghai"`, `"Asia/Kolkata"`, `"America/New_York"`.

**hour12**

Whether to use 12-hour time (as opposed to 24-hour time). Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is locale dependent.

**formatMatcher**

The format matching algorithm to use. Possible values are `"basic"` and `"best fit"`; the default is `"best fit"`. See the following paragraphs for information about the use of this property.

The following properties describe the date-time components to use in formatted output and their desired representations. Implementations are required to support at least the following subsets:

```
weekday, year, month, day, hour, minute, second
weekday, year, month, day
year, month, day
year, month
month, day
hour, minute, second
hour, minute
```

Implementations may support other subsets, and requests will be negotiated against all available subset-representation combinations to find the best match. Two algorithms are available for this negotiation and selected by the formatMatcher property: A fully specified `"basic"` algorithm and an implementation dependent "best fit" algorithm.

**weekday**

The representation of the weekday. Possible values are `"narrow"`, `"short"`, `"long"`.

**era**

The representation of the era. Possible values are `"narrow"`, `"short"`, `"long"`.

**year**

The representation of the year. Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`.

**month**

The representation of the month. Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`, `"narrow"`, `"short"`, `"long"`.

**day**

The representation of the day. Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`.

**hour**

The representation of the hour. Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`.

**minute**

The representation of the minute. Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`.

**second**

The representation of the second. Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`.

**timeZoneName**

The representation of the time zone name. Possible values are `"short"`, `"long"`.
The default value for each date-time component property is undefined, but if all component properties are undefined, then the year, month and day are assumed to be `"numeric"`.

[Check Online](https://jsbin.com/buvaketoho/5/edit?js,console)

[More Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 18):

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString()

// "3/21/2018"
```

More documentation at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 16):

We have lots of solutions for this, but I think the best of them is Moment.js. So I personally suggest to use Moment.js for date and time operations.

```js
console.log(moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16):

#### TypeScript version

It can be easily enhanced to support any format string desired. When a generic solution like this is so easy to create, and date formatting comes up so often in applications, I wouldn't recommend hard-coding date format code all over your application. It's harder to read and hides your intentions. Format strings show your intentions clearly.

##### Prototype functions

```
interface Date {
    format(formatString: string): string;
}

Date.prototype.format = function (formatString: string): string {
  return Object.entries({
    YYYY: this.getFullYear(),
    YY: this.getFullYear().toString().substring(2),
    yyyy: this.getFullYear(),
    yy: this.getFullYear().toString().substring(2),
    MMMM: this.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }),
    MMM: this.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' }),
    MM: (this.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    M: this.getMonth() + 1,
    DDDD: this.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'long' }),
    DDD: this.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'short' }),
    DD: this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    D: this.getDate(),
    dddd: this.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'long' }),
    ddd: this.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'short' }),
    dd: this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    d: this.getDate(),
    HH: this.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0'), // military
    H: this.getHours().toString(), // military
    hh: (this.getHours() % 12).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    h: (this.getHours() % 12).toString(),
    mm: this.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    m: this.getMinutes(),
    SS: this.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    S: this.getSeconds(),
    ss: this.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    s: this.getSeconds(),
    TTT: this.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0'),
    ttt: this.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0'),
    AMPM: this.getHours() < 13 ? 'AM' : 'PM',
    ampm: this.getHours() < 13 ? 'am' : 'pm',
  }).reduce((acc, entry) => {
    return acc.replace(entry[0], entry[1].toString())
  }, formatString)
}
```

##### Demo

```
function unitTest() {
    var d: Date = new Date()
    console.log(d.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')) // 12/14/2022 03:38:31
    console.log(d.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) // 2022-12-14 15:38:31
}

unitTest()
```

#### JavaScript version

It's the same. Just remove the interface, and the type names after the colons and their associated colons.

##### Snippet

```js
Date.prototype.format = function(formatString) {
  return Object.entries({
    YYYY: this.getFullYear(),
    YY: this.getFullYear().toString().substring(2),
    yyyy: this.getFullYear(),
    yy: this.getFullYear().toString().substring(2),
    MMMM: this.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long'  }),
    MMM: this.toLocaleString('default',  { month: 'short' }),
    MM: (this.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    M: this.getMonth() + 1,
    DDDD: this.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'long'  }),
    DDD: this.toLocaleDateString('default',  { weekday: 'short' }),
    DD: this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    D: this.getDate(),
    dddd: this.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'long'  }),
    ddd: this.toLocaleDateString('default',  { weekday: 'short' }),
    dd: this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    d: this.getDate(),
    HH: this.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0'), // military
    H: this.getHours().toString(), // military
    hh: (this.getHours() % 12).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    h: (this.getHours() % 12).toString(),
    mm: this.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    m: this.getMinutes(),
    SS: this.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    S: this.getSeconds(),
    ss: this.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    s: this.getSeconds(),
    TTT: this.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0'),
    ttt: this.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, '0'),
    AMPM: this.getHours() < 13 ? 'AM' : 'PM',
    ampm: this.getHours() < 13 ? 'am' : 'pm',
  }).reduce((acc, entry) => {
    return acc.replace(entry[0], entry[1].toString())
  }, formatString)
}



function unitTest() {
  var d = new Date()
  console.log(d.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')) // 12/14/2022 03:38:31
  console.log(d.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) // 2022-12-14 15:38:31
}

unitTest()
```

Comment: Not a good idea to reinvent the wheel. We have many libraries that are reliable and stable to use such as `moment`.

Comment: @Willian, idk, this works perfectly and it's tiny compared to moment. Show me where it's unreliable or unstable. Also, did you comment on all these other uglier more convoluted answers here as well?

Comment: Well, if you believe your code implementation works perfectly, is reliable, stable, and tiny compared to `moment` (as you said), just keep using it! So, this answer is getting downvoted because other experienced devs don't think it is a good solution too. So, I'd never recommend this solution to other devs, that is why I downvoted this answer. Again, not a good idea to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Willian, [moment is having a moment, at the moment](https://medium.com/rise-engineering/how-we-managed-to-shed-300kb-of-moment-js-size-in-angular-d2931d448194). I would be unkind of me to not point out to you that moment has had its moment. So find another smaller library that isn't sunsetting, which supports modularized imports. The [github](https://github.com/moment/moment) readme states it's legacy and you should pick another lib. You're behind on your research. So, after you find the best replacement, come at me again with a stronger case for libs vs roll your own.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. [Don't modify objects you don't own](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) (in this case that's the Date prototype).

Comment: there is no `format` in javascript 

Comment: @jebbie, the `format` function is defined in my answer.

Comment: .padStart(2, '0') Function is awsome solved all

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for sharing! Just a flaw though: I had to remove the "M" and "m" indexes since they were conflicting with AMPM/ampm

Answer (score 15):

If you are using jQuery UI in your code, there is an inbuilt function called `formatDate()`. I am using it this way to format today's date:

```
var testdate = Date();
testdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "d-M-yy",new Date(testdate));
alert(testdate);
```

You can see  [many other examples of formatting date in the jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Answer (score 15):

This is how I implemented for my npm plugins

```
var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October",
  "November", "December"
];

var Days = [
  "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
  "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
];

var formatDate = function(dt,format){
  format = format.replace('ss', pad(dt.getSeconds(),2));
  format = format.replace('s', dt.getSeconds());
  format = format.replace('dd', pad(dt.getDate(),2));
  format = format.replace('d', dt.getDate());
  format = format.replace('mm', pad(dt.getMinutes(),2));
  format = format.replace('m', dt.getMinutes());
  format = format.replace('MMMM', monthNames[dt.getMonth()]);
  format = format.replace('MMM', monthNames[dt.getMonth()].substring(0,3));
  format = format.replace('MM', pad(dt.getMonth()+1,2));
  format = format.replace(/M(?![ao])/, dt.getMonth()+1);
  format = format.replace('DD', Days[dt.getDay()]);
  format = format.replace(/D(?!e)/, Days[dt.getDay()].substring(0,3));
  format = format.replace('yyyy', dt.getFullYear());
  format = format.replace('YYYY', dt.getFullYear());
  format = format.replace('yy', (dt.getFullYear()+"").substring(2));
  format = format.replace('YY', (dt.getFullYear()+"").substring(2));
  format = format.replace('HH', pad(dt.getHours(),2));
  format = format.replace('H', dt.getHours());
  return format;
}

pad = function(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}
```

Comment: Which package are you referring to?

Comment: This has a bug: Month names are replaced first, then the name of the month will be replaced as well. For example `March` will become `3arch` with this code.

Comment: Change line for `'M'` to `format = format.replace("M(?!M)", (dt.getMonth()+1).toString());` and put it above line with `'MMMM'`

Comment: Demonstration of this example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/Ly8v3s0x/24/

Answer (score 14):

You should have a look at [**DayJs**](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs)  It's a remake of momentJs but modular architecture oriented so lighter.

**Fast 2kB alternative to Moment.js with the same modern API**

> Day.js is a minimalist JavaScript library that parses, validates, manipulates, and displays dates and times for modern browsers with a largely Moment.js-compatible API. If you use Moment.js, you already know how to use Day.js.

```js
var date = Date.now();
const formatedDate = dayjs(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
console.log(formatedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.16/dayjs.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

Inspired by [JD Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530967/jd-smith)'s marvellous regular expression solution, I suddenly had this head-splitting idea:

```js
var D = Date().toString().split(" ");
console.log(D[2] + "-" + D[1] + "-" + D[3]);
```

Comment: Nice variation if you need it right in the DOM like that!

Answer (score 12):

```
var today = new Date();
var formattedToday = today.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + today.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Answer (score 10):

For any one looking for a really simple ES6 solution to copy, paste and adopt:

```js
const dateToString = d => `${d.getFullYear()}-${('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${('00' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)}` 

// how to use:
const myDate = new Date(Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT'))
console.log(dateToString(myDate)) // 1995-12-04
```

Comment: Small improvement: to ensure a two digit result, this works fine: `('0' + oneOrTwoDigitNumber).slice(-2)`. There is no need to use `('00' + oneOrTwoDigitNumber).slice(-2)` because we know that oneOrTwoDigitNumber is at least one digit in length.

Answer (score 10):

As of 2019, it looks like you can get toLocaleDateString to return only certain parts and then you can join them as you wish:

```
var date = new Date();

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { day: 'numeric' }) 
            + "-"+ date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'short' })
            + "-" + date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { year: 'numeric' }) );

> 16-Nov-2019

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'long' }) 
            + " " + date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { day: 'numeric' }) 
            + ", " + date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { year: 'numeric' }) );

> November 16, 2019
```

Answer (score 10):

It works same in [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11), Firefox, and Chrome (Chrome 80.x shows 12 hours format when en-UK selected).

```js
const d = new Date('2010/08/05 23:45') // 26.3.2020
const dtfUK = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('UK', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }); //
const dtfUS = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }); //
console.log(dtfUS.format(d)); // 08/05/2010 11:45:00 PM
console.log(dtfUK.format(d)); // 05.08.2010 23:45:00
/* node.js:
08/05/2010, 11:45:00 PM
2010-08-05 23:45:00
*/
```

What about something more general?

```js
var d = new Date('2010-08-10T10:34:56.789Z');
var str = d.toDateString() + // Tue Aug 10 2010
    ' ' + d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0] + // 12:34:56, GMT+0x00 (GMT+0x:00)
    ' ' + (d.getMonth() + 101) + // 108
    ' ' + d.getMilliseconds(); // 789
console.log(str); // Tue Aug 10 2010 12:34:56 108 789
console.log(//   $1 Tue  $2 Aug  $3 11     $4 2020 $5 12   $6 34   $7 56    $8 108  $9 789
    str.replace(/(\S{3}) (\S{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) 1(\d{2}) (\d{1,3})/, '$3-$2-$4 $5:$6.$9 ($1)')
); // 10-Aug-2010 12:34.789 (Tue)
/*
$1: Tue  Week Day string
$2: Aug  Month short text
$3: 11   Day
$4: 2010 Year
$5: 12   Hour
$6: 34   Minute
$7: 56   Seconds
$8: 08   Month
$9: 789  Milliseconds
*/
```

Or for example 1-line IIFE *"library"* ;-)

```js
console.log(
    (function (frm, d) { return [d.toDateString(), d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0], (d.getMonth() + 101), d.getMilliseconds()].join(' ').replace(/(\S{3}) (\S{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) 1(\d{2}) (\d{1,3})/, frm); })
    ('$4/$8/$3 $5:$6 ($1)', new Date())
);
```

*You can remove useless parts and / or change indexes if you do not need them.*

Answer (score 10):

The JavaScript `Intl.DateTimeFormat` method provides a convenient way to format dates.

Here is how the needed format can be constructed:

```js
const date = new Date("2010-08-10");

let d=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',{year:"numeric", month:"short",day:"2-digit"}).format(date).split(" ").join("-");

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 10):

Simple formatter:

```js
function fmt(date, format = 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss') {
  const pad2 = (n) => n.toString().padStart(2, '0');

  const map = {
    YYYY: date.getFullYear(),
    MM: pad2(date.getMonth() + 1),
    DD: pad2(date.getDate()),
    hh: pad2(date.getHours()),
    mm: pad2(date.getMinutes()),
    ss: pad2(date.getSeconds()),
  };

  return Object.entries(map).reduce((prev, entry) => prev.replace(...entry), format);
}

// Usage
console.log(
  fmt(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss') // '2023-03-04T10:30:24'
);
console.log(
  fmt(new Date(), 'MM/DD/YYYY, hh:mm:ss') // '03/04/2023, 10:30:24'
);
```

Comment: Nice. Very nice

Answer (score 9):

In order to format a date as e.g. `10-Aug-2010`, you might want to use `.toDateString()` and **ES6** array destructuring.

```
const formattedDate = new Date().toDateString()
// The above yields e.g. 'Mon Jan 06 2020'

const [, month, day, year] = formattedDate.split(' ')

const ddMmmYyyy = `${day}-${month}-${year}`
// or
const ddMmmYyyy = [day, month, year].join('-')
```

Answer (score 8):

Sugar.js has excellent extensions to the Date object, including a [Date.format](http://sugarjs.com/api/Date/format) method.

Examples from the documentation:

```
Date.create().format('{Weekday} {Month} {dd}, {yyyy}');

Date.create().format('{12hr}:{mm}{tt}')
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply you can do this:

```js
let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-us', {day: 'numeric'})
let month = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-us', {month: 'long'})
let year = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-us', {year: 'numeric'})
const FormattedDate = `${date}-${month}-${year}`
console.log(FormattedDate) // 26-March-2022
```

Answer (score 7):

To obtain "10-Aug-2010", try:

```
var date = new Date('2010-08-10 00:00:00');
date = date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {day:'2-digit'}) + '-' + date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {month:'short'}) + '-' + date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {year:'numeric'})
```

For browser support, see [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I did not need a "-", here is a shorter version with time, date and time zone! date=new Date(); date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {day:'2-digit', month: 'short', year: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', timeZoneName: 'short'});  :)

Answer (score 7):

### Two pure JavaScript one-liners

In this answer I develop [JD Smith's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33131823/860099). I was able to shorten the JD Smith regexp.

```js
let format= d=> d.toString().replace(/\w+ (\w+) (\d+) (\d+).*/,'$2-$1-$3');

console.log( format(Date()) );
```

[Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103318/860099) is also based on JD Smith's idea, but he avoids regexps and give a very nice solution - I short his solution a little (by changing the *split* parameter) and opaque it in a wrapper.

```js
let format= (d,a=d.toString().split` `)=> a[2]+"-"+a[1]+"-"+a[3];

console.log( format(Date()) );
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```js
function init(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var x = d.toDateString().substr(4, 3);
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    document.querySelector("#mydate").innerHTML = day + '-' + x + '-' + year;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="mydate"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

`DateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(2010,7,10), 'DD-MMM-YYYY')`

=>`10-Aug-2010`

`DateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

=>`2017-11-22 19:52:37`

`DateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(2005, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 'D DD DDD DDDD, M MM MMM MMMM, YY YYYY, h hh H HH, m mm, s ss, a A')`

=>`2 02 Wed Wednesday, 2 02 Feb February, 05 2005, 3 03 3 03, 4 04, 5 05, am AM`

```js
var DateFormatter = {
  monthNames: [
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ],
  dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  formatDate: function (date, format) {
    var self = this;
    format = self.getProperDigits(format, /d+/gi, date.getDate());
    format = self.getProperDigits(format, /M+/g, date.getMonth() + 1);
    format = format.replace(/y+/gi, function (y) {
      var len = y.length;
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      if (len == 2)
        return (year + "").slice(-2);
      else if (len == 4)
        return year;
      return y;
    })
    format = self.getProperDigits(format, /H+/g, date.getHours());
    format = self.getProperDigits(format, /h+/g, self.getHours12(date.getHours()));
    format = self.getProperDigits(format, /m+/g, date.getMinutes());
    format = self.getProperDigits(format, /s+/gi, date.getSeconds());
    format = format.replace(/a/ig, function (a) {
      var amPm = self.getAmPm(date.getHours())
      if (a === 'A')
        return amPm.toUpperCase();
      return amPm;
    })
    format = self.getFullOr3Letters(format, /d+/gi, self.dayNames, date.getDay())
    format = self.getFullOr3Letters(format, /M+/g, self.monthNames, date.getMonth())
    return format;
  },
  getProperDigits: function (format, regex, value) {
    return format.replace(regex, function (m) {
      var length = m.length;
      if (length == 1)
        return value;
      else if (length == 2)
        return ('0' + value).slice(-2);
      return m;
    })
  },
  getHours12: function (hours) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556879/changing-the-1-24-hour-to-1-12-hour-for-the-gethours-method
    return (hours + 24) % 12 || 12;
  },
  getAmPm: function (hours) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format
    return hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  },
  getFullOr3Letters: function (format, regex, nameArray, value) {
    return format.replace(regex, function (s) {
      var len = s.length;
      if (len == 3)
        return nameArray[value].substr(0, 3);
      else if (len == 4)
        return nameArray[value];
      return s;
    })
  }
}

console.log(DateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(DateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(), 'D DD DDD DDDD, M MM MMM MMMM, YY YYYY, h hh H HH, m mm, s ss, a A'));
console.log(DateFormatter.formatDate(new Date(2005, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 'D DD DDD DDDD, M MM MMM MMMM, YY YYYY, h hh H HH, m mm, s ss, a A'));
```

The format description was taken from [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) (it does not support `Z`, UTC Timezone Offset)

> Not thoroughly tested

Answer (score 5):

Example:
"2023-04-25 00:01:23"

```js
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var startedAt = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" +
        (currentdate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + "-" +
        currentdate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + " " +
        currentdate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" +
        currentdate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" +
        currentdate.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        
        console.log(startedAt)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you fancy a short, human-readable, function - this is easily adjustable to suit you.

The **timeStamp** parameter is milliseconds from 1970 - it is returned by `new Date().getTime()` and many other devices...

OK, I changed my mind. I included an extra function for zero padding. Curses!

```
 function zeroPad(aNumber) {
     return ("0"+aNumber).slice(-2);
 }
 function humanTime(timeStamp) {
    var M = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var D = new Date(timeStamp); // 23 Aug 2016 16:45:59 <-- Desired format.
    return D.getDate() + " " + M[D.getMonth()] + " " + D.getFullYear() + " " + D.getHours() + ":" + zeroPad(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + zeroPad(D.getSeconds());
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following. It is simple and works fine.

```
 var dtFormat = require('dtformat');
   var today = new Date();
   dtFormat(today, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

Or this:

```
var now = new Date()
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
var formattedDate = now.getDate()  + "-" + months[now.getMonth()] + "-" + now.getFullYear()
alert(formattedDate)
```

Comment: Second one worked for me, without including any library. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Short, widely compatible approach:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    date.toISOString()
    .replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+).*$/, // Only extract Y-M-D
        function (a,y,m,d) {
            return [
                d, // Day
                ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',  // Month Names
                'Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
                [m-1], // Month
                y  // Year
            ].join('-') // Stitch together
        })
}
```

Or, as a single line:

```
date.toISOString().replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)Z$/, function (a,y,m,d) {return [d,['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'][m-1],y].join('-')})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are **already using ExtJS** in your project you could use [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Date):

```
var date = new Date();
Ext.Date.format(date, "d-M-Y");
```

returns:

```
"11-Nov-2015"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a new library, [smarti.to.js](https://github.com/onitecsoft/smarti.to.js), for localized formatting of JavaScript numbers, dates and JSON dates (Microsoft or ISO8601).

Example:

```
new Date('2015-1-1').to('dd.MM.yy')         // Outputs 01.01.2015
"2015-01-01T10:11:12.123Z".to('dd.MM.yy')   // Outputs 01.01.2015
```

There are also custom short patterns defined in the localization file (smarti.to.{culture}.js). Example (smarti.to.et-EE.js):

```
new Date('2015-1-1').to('d')                // Outputs 1.01.2015
```

And a multiformatting ability:

```
smarti.format('{0:n2} + {1:n2} = {2:n2}', 1, 2, 3)   // Output: 1,00 + 2,00 = 3,00
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the main answer modified to have 3-char months, and 2-digit year:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var day = date.getDate(), monthIndex = date.getMonth(), year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
    return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}

document.write(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Other way that you can format the date:

```
function formatDate(dDate,sMode){
    var today = dDate;
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd = '0'+dd
    }
    if(mm<10) {
        mm = '0'+mm
    }
    if (sMode+""==""){
        sMode = "dd/mm/yyyy";
    }
    if (sMode == "yyyy-mm-dd"){
        return  yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + "";
    }
    if (sMode == "dd/mm/yyyy"){
        return  dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`yy` = 2-digit year;
`yyyy` = full year

`M` = digit month;
`MM` = 2-digit month;
`MMM` = short month name;
`MMMM` = full month name

`EEEE` = full weekday name;
`EEE` = short weekday name

`d` = digit day;
`dd` = 2-digit day

`h` = hours;
`hh` = 2-digit hours

`m` = minutes;
`mm` = 2-digit minutes

`s` = seconds;
`ss` = 2-digit seconds

`S` = miliseconds

Used similar formating as [Class SimpleDateFormat (Java)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```js
var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var dayOfWeekNames = [
  "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
];
function formatDate(date, formatStr){
    if (!formatStr) {
      formatStr = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
    }
    var day = date.getDate(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        hour = date.getHours(),
        minute = date.getMinutes(),
        second = date.getSeconds(),
        miliseconds = date.getMilliseconds(),
        hh = twoDigitPad(hour),
        mm = twoDigitPad(minute),
        ss = twoDigitPad(second),
        EEEE = dayOfWeekNames[date.getDay()],
        EEE = EEEE.substr(0, 3),
        dd = twoDigitPad(day),
        M = month + 1,
        MM = twoDigitPad(M),
        MMMM = monthNames[month],
        MMM = MMMM.substr(0, 3),
        yyyy = year + "",
        yy = yyyy.substr(2, 2)
    ;
    return formatStr
      .replace('hh', hh).replace('h', hour)
      .replace('mm', mm).replace('m', minute)
      .replace('ss', ss).replace('s', second)
      .replace('S', miliseconds)
      .replace('dd', dd).replace('d', day)
      .replace('MMMM', MMMM).replace('MMM', MMM).replace('MM', MM).replace('M', M)
      .replace('EEEE', EEEE).replace('EEE', EEE)
      .replace('yyyy', yyyy)
      .replace('yy', yy)
    ;
}
function twoDigitPad(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}
console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss:S'));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm'));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:S'));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'yy-MM-dd hh:mm'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This function was inspired by Java's SimpleDateFormat provides various formats such as:

```
dd-MMM-yyyy → 17-Jul-2018
yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssXX → 20180717T120856+0900
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX → 2018-07-17T12:08:56+09:00
E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z → Tue, 17 Jul 2018 12:08:56 +0900
yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss Z → 2018.07.17 at 12:08:56 +0900
EEE, MMM d, ''yy → Tue, Jul 17, '18
h:mm a → 12:08 PM
hh 'o''''clock' a, X → 12 o'clock PM, +09
```

**Code example:**

```js
function formatWith(formatStr, date, opts) {

    if (!date) {
        date = new Date();
    }

    opts = opts || {};

    let _days = opts.days;

    if (!_days) {
        _days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    }

    let _months = opts.months;

    if (!_months) {
        _months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    }

    const pad = (number, strDigits, isUnpad) => {
        const strNum = number.toString();
        if (!isUnpad && strNum.length > strDigits.length) {
            return strNum;
        } else {
            return ('0000' + strNum).slice(-strDigits.length);
        }
    };

    const timezone = (date, letter) => {
        const chunk = [];
        const offset = -date.getTimezoneOffset();
        chunk.push(offset === 0 ? 'Z' : offset > 0 ? '+' : '-');//add Z or +,-
        if (offset === 0) return chunk;
        chunk.push(pad(Math.floor(offset / 60), '00'));//hour
        if (letter === 'X') return chunk.join('');
        if (letter === 'XXX') chunk.push(':');
        chunk.push(pad((offset % 60), '00'));//min
        return chunk.join('');
    };

    const ESCAPE_DELIM = '\0';
    const escapeStack = [];

    const escapedFmtStr = formatStr.replace(/'.*?'/g, m => {
        escapeStack.push(m.replace(/'/g, ''));
        return ESCAPE_DELIM + (escapeStack.length - 1) + ESCAPE_DELIM;
    });

    const formattedStr = escapedFmtStr
        .replace(/y{4}|y{2}/g, m => pad(date.getFullYear(), m, true))
        .replace(/M{3}/g, m => _months[date.getMonth()])
        .replace(/M{1,2}/g, m => pad(date.getMonth() + 1, m))
        .replace(/M{1,2}/g, m => pad(date.getMonth() + 1, m))
        .replace(/d{1,2}/g, m => pad(date.getDate(), m))
        .replace(/H{1,2}/g, m => pad(date.getHours(), m))
        .replace(/h{1,2}/g, m => {
            const hours = date.getHours();
            return pad(hours === 0 ? 12 : hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours, m);
        })
        .replace(/a{1,2}/g, m => date.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM')
        .replace(/m{1,2}/g, m => pad(date.getMinutes(), m))
        .replace(/s{1,2}/g, m => pad(date.getSeconds(), m))
        .replace(/S{3}/g, m => pad(date.getMilliseconds(), m))
        .replace(/[E]+/g, m => _days[date.getDay()])
        .replace(/[Z]+/g, m => timezone(date, m))
        .replace(/X{1,3}/g, m => timezone(date, m))
    ;

    const unescapedStr = formattedStr.replace(/\0\d+\0/g, m => {
        const unescaped = escapeStack.shift();
        return unescaped.length > 0 ? unescaped : '\'';
    });

    return unescapedStr;
}

// Let's format with above function
const dateStr = '2018/07/17 12:08:56';
const date = new Date(dateStr);
const patterns = [
    "dd-MMM-yyyy",
    "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssXX",//ISO8601
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX",//ISO8601EX
    "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",//RFC1123(RFC822) like email
    "yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss Z",//hh shows 1-12
    "EEE, MMM d, ''yy",
    "h:mm a",
    "hh 'o''''clock' a, X",
];

for (let pattern of patterns) {
    console.log(`${pattern} → ${formatWith(pattern, date)}`);
}
```

**And you can use this as a library**

It is also released as an NPM module. You can use this on Node.js or use this from a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for a browser.

**Node.js**

```
const {SimpleDateFormat} = require('@riversun/simple-date-format');
```

**In the browser**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riversun/simple-date-format@1.0.2/dist/simple-date-format.js"></script>
```

Write the code as follows.

```
const date = new Date('2018/07/17 12:08:56');
const sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
console.log(sdf.formatWith("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", date));//to be "2018-07-17T12:08:56+09:00"
```

**Source code here on GitHub**:

https://github.com/riversun/simple-date-format

Answer (score 2):

Use this procedure

```js
const MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

const date = new Date()

const dateString = `${date.getDate()}-${MONTHS[date.getMonth()]}-${date.getFullYear()}`

console.log(dateString)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have formatted the date from **'01/07/2022'** to **'2022-07-01'**:

```js
const formatDate = date => {
    const d = new Date(date)
    let month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString()
    let day = d.getDate().toString()
    const year = d.getFullYear()
    if (month.length < 2) {
        month = '0' + month
    }
    if (day.length < 2) {
        day = '0' + day
    }
    return [ year, month, day ].join('-')
}

console.log(formatDate('01/07/2022'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that does exactly what you want

https://github.com/UziTech/js-date-format

```
var d = new Date("2010-8-10");
document.write(d.format("DD-MMM-YYYY"));
```

Comment: Extending native prototypes is not a good idea. There are plenty of other tools out there, like Moment.js, that accomplish the same thing without touching the Date prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will allow you to format the date to either `DD-MM-YYYY` (27-12-2017) or `DD MMM YYYY` (27 Dec 2017) :

```
/** Pad number to fit into nearest power of 10 */
function padNumber(number, prependChar, count) {
  var out = '' + number; var i;
  if (number < Math.pow(10, count))
    while (out.length < ('' + Math.pow(10, count)).length) out = prependChar + out;
  
  return out;
}

/* Format the date to 'DD-MM-YYYY' or 'DD MMM YYYY' */
function dateToDMY(date, useNumbersOnly) {
  var months = [
    'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 
    'Nov', 'Dec'
  ];

  return '' + padNumber(date.getDate(), '0', 1) + 
   (useNumbersOnly? '-' + padNumber(date.getMonth() + 1, '0', 1) + '-' : ' ' + months[date.getMonth()] + ' ')
    + date.getFullYear();
}
```

Change the order of `date.getFullYear()` and `padNumber(date.getDate(), '0', 1)` to make a `dateToYMD()` function.

See [repl.it example](https://replit.com/@codymims/RealCruelMeerkat) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I know someone might say that this is silly solution, but it does do the trick by removing the unnecessary information from the date string.

`yourDateObject` produces:

Wed Dec 13 2017 20:40:40 GMT+0200 (EET)

`yourDateObject.toString().slice(0, 15);` produces:

Wed Dec 13 2017

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any libraries. Just extract date components and construct the string. Here is how to get `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Also note the month index  "January is 0, February is 1, and so on."

```
// @flow

type Components = {
  day: number,
  month: number,
  year: number
}

export default class DateFormatter {
  // YYYY-MM-DD
  static YYYY_MM_DD = (date: Date): string => {
    const components = DateFormatter.format(DateFormatter.components(date))
    return `${components.year}-${components.month}-${components.day}`
  }

  static format = (components: Components) => {
    return {
      day: `${components.day}`.padStart(2, '0'),
      month: `${components.month}`.padStart(2, '0'),
      year: components.year
    }
  }

  static components = (date: Date) => {
    return {
      day: date.getDate(),
      month: date.getMonth() + 1,
      year: date.getFullYear()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function that can return the date, the date + time, or just the time:

```
var myDate = dateFormatter("2019-01-24 11:33:24", "date-time");
// >> RETURNS "January 24, 2019 11:33:24"

var myDate2 = dateFormatter("2019-01-24 11:33:24", "date");
// >> RETURNS "January 24, 2019"

var myDate3 = dateFormatter("2019-01-24 11:33:24", "time");
// >> RETURNS "11:33:24"


function dateFormatter(strDate, format){
    var theDate = new Date(strDate);
    if (format=="time")
       return getTimeFromDate(theDate);
    else{
       var dateOptions = {year:'numeric', month:'long', day:'numeric'};
       var formattedDate = theDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", + dateOptions);
       if (format=="date")
           return formattedDate;
       return formattedDate + " " + getTimeFromDate(theDate);
    }
}

function getTimeFromDate(theDate){
    var sec = theDate.getSeconds();
    if (sec<10)
        sec = "0" + sec;
    var min = theDate.getMinutes();
    if (min<10)
        min = "0" + min;
    return theDate.getHours() + ':'+ min + ':' + sec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This module](http://locutus.io/php/datetime/date/) can easily handle mostly every case there is.
It is part of a bigger npm package, by Locutus, which includes a variety of functions, but it can be used totally independent of the package itself, just copy paste/ adapt a little if not working with npm (change from a module to just a function).

As a second parameter it accepts a timestamp, which can come from anywhere, such as Date.getTime().

Also, Locutus maintains a bigger datetime module, also inside the *locutus* package which will give a more object-oriented way to use it.

[Here](http://locutus.io/php/datetime/) you can see other datetime functions, as modules, that proved to be very useful too.

You can find documentation on parameters and format strings [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (note that the documentation site is a PHP site, but the locutus implementation follows exactly the same specifications).

Examples of the **date** Module

```
date('H:m:s \\m \\i\\s \\m\\o\\n\\t\\h', 1062402400)//'07:09:40 m is month'

date('F j, Y, g:i a', 1062462400)//'September 2, 2003, 12:26 am'

date('Y W o', 1062462400)//'2003 36 2003'

var $x = date('Y m d', (new Date()).getTime() / 1000) $x = $x + '' var $result = $x.length // 2009 01 09    10

date('W', 1104534000)    //'52'

date('B t', 1104534000)    //'999 31'

date('W U', 1293750000.82); // 2010-12-31    '52 1293750000'

date('W', 1293836400); // 2011-01-01    '52'

date('W Y-m-d', 1293974054); // 2011-01-02    '52 2011-01-02'
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function convert_month(i = 0, option = "num") { // i = index

  var object_months = [
    { num: 01, short: "Jan", long: "January" },
    { num: 02, short: "Feb", long: "Februari" }, 
    { num: 03, short: "Mar", long: "March" },          
    { num: 04, short: "Apr", long: "April" },
    { num: 05, short: "May", long: "May" },
    { num: 06, short: "Jun", long: "Juni" },
    { num: 07, short: "Jul", long: "July" },
    { num: 08, short: "Aug", long: "August" },
    { num: 09, short: "Sep", long: "September" },
    { num: 10, short: "Oct", long: "October" },
    { num: 11, short: "Nov", long: "November" },
    { num: 12, short: "Dec", long: "December" }
  ];
        
  return object_months[i][option];

}
      
var d = new Date();
      
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript
var num   = `${d.getDate()}-${convert_month(d.getMonth())}-${d.getFullYear()}`;
var short = `${d.getDate()}-${convert_month(d.getMonth(), "short")}-${d.getFullYear()}`;
var long  = `${d.getDate()}-${convert_month(d.getMonth(), "long")}-${d.getFullYear()}`;

document.querySelector("#num").innerHTML = num;
document.querySelector("#short").innerHTML = short;
document.querySelector("#long").innerHTML = long;
```

```html
<p>Numeric  : <span id="num"></span> (default)</p>
<p>Short    : <span id="short"></span></p>
<p>Long     : <span id="long"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though [`new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172083/1028230) is tres hipster and good for my normal use case, I didn't love any of the first few answers for a more customized string, and gave myself a few minutes to go as hipster [golfy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) & one-linery as possible.

I didn't *quite* see the solution I came up with, so here it is...

```
((d,x)=>`${d.getFullYear()}-${x(d.getMonth()+1)}-${x(d.getDate())}`)
    (new Date(), (x)=>x.toString().padStart(2,"0"))

// today that produces
// '2022-09-28'
// the same as new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
// but provides a good framework for other orders or values
```

Pseudo-[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for the win.

The problems solved here, of course, are...

1. You may need to format days and months less than 10 with leading zeroes.

   - So pass in a function that casts to string & `padStart`s.
2. You need to get the same date in there without going `new Date()` over and over.

   - Get "now" (`new Date()`) and pass in as a parameter to reuse.
3. You gotta add 1 to `getMonth`.

   - Do that.

You could do similar tricks even if you needed to map to month abbreviations or something, not that it'd be very cute.

```
((d,x,y)=>`${x(d.getDate())} ${y(d.getMonth())} ${d.getFullYear()}`)
    (
     new Date(), 
     (x)=>x.toString().padStart(2,"0"), 
     (m)=>"jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec".split(',')[m]
    )

// As of this writing, that yields...
// '28 sep 2022'
```

(obviously remove whitespace from both for increased golfness; didn't want code blocks to scroll)

... though I'd have a hard time recommending that for anything but creating test values from the console for some strange reason. Really weird that there's no `toString('yyyy-mm-dd')`, and that's as close as I could get in a line.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) plugin to your page:

```
function DateFormate(dateFormate, datetime) {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormate, datetime);
};
```

Comment: Don't add jQuery and jQuery UI just to format a date!

Comment: if you already using Jquery UI in your project it could be a good approach,but it seems you can only show the date portion , no hours, minutes or seconds

Comment: why not plain jquery? $.format.date(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

Comment: @Alexander That is not plain jquery, that's another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
thisDate = new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
formattedDate = (thisDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (thisDate.getDate()+1) + "/" + thisDate.getFullYear();
```

This takes a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) date, "/Date(1429573751663)/" and produces as the formatted string:

"4/21/2015"

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format).

Answer (score 0):

2.39KB minified. One file. https://github.com/rhroyston/clock-js

10-Aug-2010 would be:

```
var str = clock.month
str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1,3); //gets you "Aug"
console.log(clock.day + '-' + str + '-' + clock.year); //gets you 10-Aug-2010
```

Comment: Still having to do stuff like `str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1,3);` kinda defeats the purpose of using a library. Why don't you add out-of-the-box support for three letter month formats? Also, you might want to consider adding internationalization to you library, as a library like this would be kinda useless for non-English websites without it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some ready-to-paste time/date formatting code that does *not* rely on any external modules/libraries or use jQuery or ES7 or anything.  Unlike the code in some other answers, this code offers this combination of features:

- it takes a JavaScript Date object as input
- it can display date as local time zone or UTC
- it uses a simple formatting system "{year4} {month02} {second}" that is easy to read and understand even after you write the code, unlike the typical "%D %m %-" which always forces you back to the documentation
- the formatting system does not have any weird self-collisions like some ad-hoc "DD MM YYYY" systems
- you can run the test right here and try it

```js
// format_date(date, pattern, utc)
// - date
//   - a JavaScript Date object
//   - use "new Date()" for current time
// - pattern
//   - a string with embedded {codes} like
//     "{year4}-{month02}-{day02}: {dayname3}"
//     see format_date_funcs below for complete list
//   - any other letters go through unchanged
// - utc
//   - if true, shows date in UTC time "zone"
//   - if false/omitted, shows date in local time zone
//
var month_names =
[
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var day_of_week_names =
[
  "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
];

function space_pad2(num)
{
    return num < 10 ? " " + num : num;
}

function zero_pad2(num)
{
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}

function space_pad3(num)
{
    if (num < 10)
        return "  " + num;
    else if (num < 100)
        return " " + num;
    else
        return num;
}

function zero_pad3(num)
{
    if (num < 10)
        return "00" + num;
    else if (num < 100)
        return "0" + num;
    else
        return num;
}

var format_date_funcs =
{
    // {year4}  = '1902'
    // {year02} =   '02'
    //
    'year4': function(date, utc)
    {
        var year = utc ? date.getUTCFullYear() : date.getFullYear();
        return year;
    },
    'year02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var year = utc ? date.getUTCFullYear() : date.getFullYear();
        return year.toString().substr(2,2);
    },
    // {month}   =  '1' - '12'
    // {month2}  = ' 1' - '12' (space padded)
    // {month02} = '01' - '12'
    //
    'month': function(date, utc)
    {
        var month = utc ? date.getUTCMonth() : date.getMonth(); // [0,11]
        return            month + 1;
    },
    'month2': function(date, utc)
    {
        var month = utc ? date.getUTCMonth() : date.getMonth(); // [0,11]
        return space_pad2(month + 1);
    },
    'month02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var month = utc ? date.getUTCMonth() : date.getMonth(); // [0,11]
        return zero_pad2(month + 1);
    },
    // {monthname}  = 'January'
    // {monthname3} = 'Jan'
    //
    'monthname': function(date, utc)
    {
        var month = utc ? date.getUTCMonth() : date.getMonth(); // [0,11]
        return month_names[month];
    },
    'monthname3': function(date, utc)
    {
        var month = utc ? date.getUTCMonth() : date.getMonth(); // [0,11]
        return month_names[month].substr(0, 3);
    },
    // {day}   =  '1' - '31'
    // {day2}  = ' 1' - '31' (space padded)
    // {day02} = '01' - '31'
    //
    'day': function(date, utc)
    {
        var date = utc ? date.getUTCDate() : date.getDate(); // [1,31]
        return date;
    },
    'day2': function(date, utc)
    {
        var date = utc ? date.getUTCDate() : date.getDate(); // [1,31]
        return space_pad2(date);
    },
    'day02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var date = utc ? date.getUTCDate() : date.getDate(); // [1,31]
        return zero_pad2(date);
    },
    // {dayname}  = 'Tuesday'
    // {dayname3} = 'Tue'
    //
    'dayname': function(date, utc)
    {
        var day = utc ? date.getUTCDay() : date.getDay(); // [0,6]
        return day_of_week_names[day];
    },
    'dayname3': function(date, utc)
    {
        var day = utc ? date.getUTCDay() : date.getDay(); // [0,6]
        return day_of_week_names[day].substr(0,3);
    },
    // {24hour}   =  '0' - '23'
    // {24hour2}  = ' 0' - '23' (space padded)
    // {24hour02} = '00' - '23'
    //
    '24hour': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        return hour;
    },
    '24hour2': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        return space_pad2(hour);
    },
    '24hour02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        return zero_pad2(hour);
    },
    // {12hour}   =  '1' - '12'
    // {12hour2}  = ' 1' - '12' (space padded)
    // {12hour02} = '01' - '12'
    // {ampm}     = 'am' or 'pm'
    // {AMPM}     = 'AM' or 'PM'
    //
    '12hour': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        hour = hour % 12; // [0,11]
        if (0 === hour) hour = 12;
        return hour;
    },
    '12hour2': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        hour = hour % 12; // [0,11]
        if (0 === hour) hour = 12;
        return space_pad2(hour);
    },
    '12hour02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        hour = hour % 12; // [0,11]
        if (0 === hour) hour = 12;
        return zero_pad2(hour);
    },
    'ampm': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        return (hour < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
    },
    'AMPM': function(date, utc)
    {
        var hour = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours(); // [0,23]
        return (hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
    },
    // {minute}   =  '0' - '59'
    // {minute2}  = ' 0' - '59' (space padded)
    // {minute02} = '00' - '59'
    //
    'minute': function(date, utc)
    {
        var minute = utc ? date.getUTCMinutes() : date.getMinutes(); // [0,59]
        return minute;
    },
    'minute2': function(date, utc)
    {
        var minute = utc ? date.getUTCMinutes() : date.getMinutes(); // [0,59]
        return space_pad2(minute);
    },
    'minute02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var minute = utc ? date.getUTCMinutes() : date.getMinutes(); // [0,59]
        return zero_pad2(minute);
    },
    // {second}   =  '0' - '59'
    // {second2}  = ' 0' - '59' (space padded)
    // {second02} = '00' - '59'
    //
    'second': function(date, utc)
    {
        var second = utc ? date.getUTCSeconds() : date.getSeconds(); // [0,59]
        return second;
    },
    'second2': function(date, utc)
    {
        var second = utc ? date.getUTCSeconds() : date.getSeconds(); // [0,59]
        return space_pad2(second);
    },
    'second02': function(date, utc)
    {
        var second = utc ? date.getUTCSeconds() : date.getSeconds(); // [0,59]
        return zero_pad2(second);
    },
    // {msec}   =   '0' - '999'
    // {msec3}  = '  0' - '999' (space padded)
    // {msec03} = '000' - '999'
    //
    'msec': function(date, utc)
    {
        var msec =
            utc ? date.getUTCMilliseconds() : date.getMilliseconds(); // [0,999]
        return msec;
    },
    'msec3': function(date, utc)
    {
        var msec =
            utc ? date.getUTCMilliseconds() : date.getMilliseconds(); // [0,999]
        return space_pad3(msec);
    },
    'msec03': function(date, utc)
    {
        var msec =
            utc ? date.getUTCMilliseconds() : date.getMilliseconds(); // [0,999]
        return zero_pad3(msec);
    },
    // {open} = '{' (in case you actually want '{' in the output)
    //
    'open': function(date, utc)
    {
        return '{';
    },
    // {close} = '}' (in case you actually want '}' in the output)
    //
    'close': function(date, utc)
    {
        return '}';
    },
};

function format_date(date, pattern, utc)
{
    if (!pattern)
    {
        pattern = '{month}/{day}/{year4}';
    }

    var ret = '';

    while (pattern.length > 0)
    {
        var s = pattern.indexOf('{');
        var e = pattern.indexOf('}');
        //console.log('s ' + s + ' e ' + e);
        if (-1 !== s && -1 !== e && s < e)
        {
            // - there is a well-formed {foo} in range [s,e]
            // - first we emit range [0,s) as literal
        }
        else
        {
            // - rest of string has no {} or has malformed }{ or { or }
            // - just emit the rest of the string as literal and be done
            s = pattern.length;
        }
        // emit range [0,s) as literal
        if (s > 0)
        {
            ret += pattern.substr(0, s);
            pattern = pattern.substr(s);
            e -= s;
            s = 0;
        }

        if (0 === pattern.length) break;

        // emit range [s=0,e] by evaluating code
        console.assert(0 === s); // position of {
        console.assert(e > 0);  // position of }
        console.assert('{' === pattern.substr(s, 1));
        console.assert('}' === pattern.substr(e, 1));
        var code = pattern.substr(1,e-1);
        var func = format_date_funcs[code];
        console.assert(func);
        ret += func(date, utc);

        pattern = pattern.substr(e+1);
    }

    return ret;
}

if (1) // test format_date
{
    var fmt = '[';
    for (var func in format_date_funcs)
    {
        if (!format_date_funcs.hasOwnProperty(func)) continue;
        fmt += '{' + func + '}/';
    }
    fmt += ']';
    var now = new Date();
    console.log(fmt);
    console.log(format_date(now, fmt, false /* utc */));
    console.log(format_date(now, fmt, true /* utc */));
}
```

Comment: There is a ***huge*** amount of redundancy in this code. Is it really necessary?

Comment: I'm sure you could scrunch it down, but I like having each case spelled out for readability.  Especially the 'foo' 'foo2' 'foo02' cases because all 3 cases don't always apply for every 'foo' and it's simpler to explain that by showing everything in a list.  Keeping it simple and easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps some one who are looking for multiple date formats one after the other by willingly or unexpectedly. Please find the code: I am using the Moment.js format function on a current date as (today is 29-06-2020): `var startDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY');` Result: 06/28/20

It retains only the year part: 20 as "06/28/20", after if I run the statement `new Date(startDate)`, the result is "Mon Jun 28 1920 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".

Then, when I use another format on "06/28/20": startDate = moment(startDate ).format('MM-DD-YYYY'); Result: 06-28-1920, in Google Chrome and Firefox browsers, it gives the correct date on the second attempt as: 06-28-2020.

But in Internet Explorer it is having issues. From this I understood we can apply one dateformat on the given date. If we want a second date format, it should be apply on the fresh date, not on the first date format result. And also observe that for the first time applying 'MM-DD-YYYY' and next 'MM-DD-YY' is working in Internet Explorer. For a clear understanding, please find my question in the link: Date went wrong when using Moment.js date format in [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11).

Answer (score 0):

##### String conversion

```js
// date 
const dateConvert = {
  dasher: dt => {
    let m = (dt.getMonth() + 1) === 13 ? 1 : (dt.getMonth() + 1);
    m = m < 10 ? `0${m}` : m.toString();
    let d = dt.getDate();
    d = d < 10 ? `0${d}` : d.toString();
    return `${dt.getFullYear()}-${m}-${d}`;
  }, 
  slasher: dt => {
    return dateConvert.slash(dateConvert.dasher(dt));
  }, 
  dash: str => {
    // 03/11/2022 -> 2022-03-11
    let [d, m, y] = str.split('/');
    return `${y}-${m}-${d}`;
  }, 
  slash: str => {
    // 2022-03-11 -> 03/11/2022
    let [y, m, d] = str.split('-');
    return `${d}/${m}/${y}`
  }
}

// console.log(dateConvert.dasher(new Date('01/31/2001')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this code for adding days and format to a date.

```
 const FechaMaxima = new Date();
 FechaMaxima.setDate(FechaMaxima.getDate() + 6);
 FechaMaxima.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score -2):

I just split it with 'T'

```
  date = "2023-11-15T00:00:00.000+00:00"
  myDate = date.split('T')[0]
```

Answer (score -3):

Formatting Date to different formats

```js
let objectDate = new Date();



let day = objectDate.getDate();
console.log(day); // 12


let currentmo = objectDate.getMonth();
month = currentmo + 1;
console.log(month + 1); // 1


let year = objectDate.getFullYear();
console.log(year); // 2023



// Now you can set it accordingly


// dd/mm/yyyy
console.log(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);


// mm/dd/yyyy
console.log(month + '/' + day + '/' + year);
```

Try out this code - https://bbbootstrap.com/code/format-date-javascript-49065802

Answer (score -5):

This can help:

```
export const formatDateToString = date => {
    if (!date) {
        return date;
    }
    try {
        return format(parse(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    } catch (error) {
        return 'invalid date';
    }
};
```