# replace multiple occurences in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have a selectbox with parameters as the value in the option, set like this:

```
<option value="{$i.tileid}androoftiletypeeq{$i.model}andproducenteq{$i.producent}">{$i.name} {$i.$title}</option>
```

I am trying to replace all "and" and "eq" to "&" and "=", but I can only get my javascript to replace the first occurrence. The form is named / ID'ed "rooftile_select

```
$("#rooftile_select").change(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); 

  var data = $("#rooftile_select").serialize();                
  var pathname = window.location;
  var finalurl = pathname+'&'+data;

  var replaced = finalurl.replace("and", "&").replace("eq", "=");
});
```

The last parameters in finalurl then looks like this:

```
&rid=56&rooftiletype=9andproducenteqs
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multiple replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)

Comment: This answer might provide a solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/what-are-useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var replaced = finalurl.replace(/and/g, '&').replace(/eq/g, '=');
```

This should do the trick. With the `g` after the `/` you're saying that you want to replace all occurences.

Comment: This would replace "sand" with "s&" and "equation" with "=uation". Just be aware of that in case you're passing words like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
replaced = finalurl.replace(/and/g, "&").replace(/eq/g, "=");
```

Answer (score 1):

## Since ES12

As of August 2020, modern browsers have support for the `String.replaceAll()` method defined by the ECMAScript 2021 (**ES12**) language specification.

```
var replaced = finalurl.replaceAll('and', '&').replaceAll('eq', '=');
```

## Otherwise

We can do a full replacement only if we supply the pattern as a regular expression

```
var replaced = finalurl.replace(/and/g, '&').replace(/eq/g, '=');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp with *global* flag

```
var finalurl = '{$i.tileid}androoftiletypeeq{$i.model}andproducenteq{$i.producent}';
finalurl.replace(/and/g, "&").replace(/eq/g, "=")
```

If your string is always going to contain `{...}` variables in it, you can use following to avoid accidently replacing the variable or request parameter name

```
finalurl.replace(/\}and/g, "}&").replace(/eq\{/g, "={")
```