# string.replace("é", "e") not working

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have function that is supposed to "clean" a string and i'd like to use replace() to do that, but I can't figure out why the following code is not working when the text comes from an input[text].

for instance :

```
console.log(getCleanText("ééé")); // works fine, it displays : eee
```

but

```
// my_id is an input with type="text"
var my_text = document.getElementById("my_id").value 
console.log(getCleanText(my_text)); // doesn't work at all, it displays : ééé
```

the function code is :

```
function getCleanText(some_text) {
    var clean_text = some_text.toLowerCase();
    clean_text = clean_text.replace("é", "e"); 
    clean_text = clean_text.split("é").join("e"); // give it another try

    return clean_text;
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: FWIW, do you know that `clean_text.replace("é", "e")` will replace only the first `é` with `e`?

Comment: I didn't, thanx for the info, but that doesn't explain why none is being replaced :/

Comment: Working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/2QaWJ/

Comment: Try `clean_text.replace(/é/g, "e")` instead of `clean_text.replace("é", "e")`.

Comment: Working for me too http://jsfiddle.net/9RpAr/

Comment: Ok, so it means I have a problem with my computer configuration then. If anyone has ever had that kind of issue I'd be happy to know how he solved it...

Comment: Check whether your file is stored with the proper encoding. It should be "UTF-8".

Comment: maybe it deals with your computer's default language configuration...what kind of keyboard is set up for your computer?

Comment: I tried your version Aadit M Shah but it still displays ééé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the character "é" from element value is the different from the "é" constant. To resolve that you can take look at the int value of the input.

```
var inputEValue = document.getElementById("my_id").charCodeAt(0);
var constantEValue = "é".charCodeAt(0);
```

Then you will be able to detect what characters you are replacing. 
If you want to just remove accents from text, take look at the question [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings)

Comment: Indeed, I have the code 233 for my input and i have 65533 for the constant

Answer (score 4):

I'm willing to bet your problem lies in a misunderstanding of Unicode.

```
é 
é
```

Those two characters above are two different characters.  The first is the [letter e](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0065/index.htm), with an accent character ([U+0301](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm)). The other is a single character, [U+00E9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm).

You need to ensure you're replacing *both* versions.

Comment: Most intuitive answer of the lot. +1

Comment: I tried several things to check on that but i dont really know how to ensure i'm using both.

Comment: I gave a shot by using "\u00E9" and "\u0301" and it works fine ! Thanx a lot. But now I'm wondering how I will replace all those funky chars...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function cleanText(text) {
    var re = new RegExp(/\u0301|\u00e9/g);

    return text.replace(re, "e").toLowerCase();
}

cleanText("éééé")
```

--

Updated to use the proposed UniCode chars by Matt Grande

Comment: Hmm -- if the input text consists of "e,acute" then your code will return "ee". You are better off replacing all combining accents with nothing, and then check for precomposed characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getCleanText(old_string)
{
    var new_string = old_string.toLowerCase();
    return new_string.replace(/é/g, 'e');
}
```

Ed: beaten by the Robert. For reference, see here: [What are useful JavaScript methods that extends built-in objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/what-are-useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579)

Comment: How about simply `return old_string.toLowerCase().replace(/é/g, 'e')`?

Comment: That works, of course. I just try to avoid crazy chaining of methods.

Comment: You could always put a newline in between: `return old_string.toLowerCase()
/* newline */
.replace(/é/g, 'e')`

Comment: True, but a single variable hardly adds any overhead.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of 
`var my_text = document.getElementById("my_id").value;` ?
Depending on your html, you might need to use other functions to get the data. e.g
`var my_text = document.getElementById("my_id").innerHTML`;

http://jsbin.com/obAmiPe/5/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: the output is ééé. I tried to replace .value by .innerHtml and .innerText but it gives the same result