# replace multiple <br> tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the multiple `<br />` tags with single `<br />` using JavaScript in a text.
my text like:

```
some text.<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
some text
```

I tried this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<br /> <br />
    <br /> <br /><br /> <br />/g,"<br />"); </script>
```

but it did not work .

Comment: So what JavaScript have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/what-are-useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579

Comment: I tried this code:
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />/g,"<br />");
</script>
but it did not work

Comment: Do you want to replace occurences of `"<br />"` in a string, or `<br />` elements in the DOM?

Comment: @AhmedElshorbagy: To improve your question, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Comment: and show us the error, and where do you think it went wrong.

Comment: @pawel I want to replace these 7 <br /> tags with one or two <br /> tags

Comment: @AhmedElshorbagy But where you're getting that text from? Is it in a JS string, or is it within some element showed on your page?

Comment: in this page
http://www.royaltytrips.com/hotel/waikiki-resort-hotel/

@teemu html body

Comment: I think it's misleading to treat this question as a duplicate of "how to replace a string" and pointing to inferior (IMO) regex-based solution when a DOM-based method is arguably a better fit in this context. The intent was to replace elements, not strings, after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified that it's in `document.body`, so in the DOM. Then you can (and you should) use DOM methods:

```
var siblingBrs = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('br + br') );
siblingBrs.forEach( function( br ){
    br.parentNode.removeChild( br );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jL8jkkt0/

Notice it's agnostic to the string representation of a `<br />` element in the source code.

BTW if it's only for display purposes (to avoid visual gap) you can just use CSS:

```
br + br { display:none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jL8jkkt0/1/

Answer (score 1):

First get the HTML as string then replace it using regex:

```js
var s = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = s.replace(/(\<br[\s]*\/?\>[\s]*)+/g, '<br/>');
```

```html
First Line<br><br /><br/><br><br /><br/>Second Line
```

Comment: recommending regex to manipulate HTML is a poor advice http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4879

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var stripped = original.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>){3,}/gi, '<br>');
```

Substituting different values here...

```
{3,}
```

...will allow you to control at what count the removal occurs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
var newText = oldText.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>){3,}/gi, '<br>');
```

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r5bu1xq2/